# Weird behavior when migrating a migrated question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

I'm looking at this question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/178311/wifi-what-can-be-wrong-with-my-router-closed
It states that it was migrated from StackOverflow, and after it got migrated to SuperUser, it gives a description of why it was migrated but does not actually state that it was migrated or give a link for where it was migrated to. This seems like improper behavior. At least there should be a link to [WiFi, what can be wrong with my router](https://superuser.com/questions/185020/wifi-what-can-be-wrong-with-my-router) so people could follow the question.

So is this correct behavior? Should it be changed? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't really support multiple migrations. Every time I've seen it, there are deeper problems-- either the question needs to be deleted, or should never have been migrated off the source site.

For now, when this happens (it's rare), just flag it for moderator attention or email the address at the bottom of every page.