# Need option "belongs to CodeReview" in "close because off-topic" button

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

Today I found a new StackExchange site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, and I'm sure I'll see a lot of questions in my RSS, which I will want to vote to send there, but I can't.

Comment: Bump on this. I'm increasingly seeing code review questions on SO, and it would really be nice to be able to close as off-topic and suggest that they belong on Code Review.

Comment: If you want `codereview` to grow and get more traffic, making migrating stuff there from `so` would be the easiest way to declutter `so` and drive traffic to `codereview`.

Comment: @Jarrod but what kind of traffic would that be? I predict the majority would be `I run code but get error why it not work plz help!?!?!?!?!` traffic fit to destroy CodeReview.SE within three weeks

Comment: it would be just **awesome** if this brave new option [replaces "belongs to Programmers"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Comment: +1. In my opinion referrals to Code Review would be more common than referrals to (existing close options) serverfault.com or superuser.com (at least, for the off-topic questions I see, which tend to be mostly in the JavaScript/jQuery/html/CSS categories).

Answer (score 10):

History tells this definitely will not happen until the site "releases" officially.

Comment: And probably not even then. The migrate dialog is limited to 5 options and one of those is Meta.

Comment: @ChrisF that seems kind of a pity...Is it really impossible to add other sites if the need ever arises?

Comment: @Crazy It's not out of impossibility; it's by design. Offering users the chance to migrate to anywhere would make the choice too hard and overly complex.

Comment: What do you mean by "releases" officially? As in leaves private beta, or leaves public beta?

Comment: The latter, @Andrew.

Answer (score 8):

If you see a question that you think would be a better fit for another site not on the migration list flag it for moderator attention explaining where you think it should go.

Moderators can migrate a question **anywhere** on the network.

Comment: Is it sensible doing this for old questions posted (sometimes long) before the target site launched? I sometimes do this for programmers (especially when the question is deleted and is a good fit for programmers) and some posts have been migrated, but I'm somewhat cautious not to overdo it.

Comment: @marcog - I wouldn't do it for any old questions. It makes no sense to clutter the new site, plus for a site like Programmers' where **the remit has evolved over time** the question might not actually be a fit any more.

Answer (score 4):

It could be code review (I just flagged one to migrate it there yesterday) or it could be some other site, like game development. I would like to see a text box labeled "other" below the standard options to suggest the place. Of course, the mods will then act as they seem fit, but that option may make their job a little easier.

Comment: Just do as you are doing now. Flag it and name the site. If your suggestion were implemented someone would have to look at the flag anyway.

Comment: Sure, but given the amount of related sites in SE, it seems counter-intuitive to limit the off-topic suggestions to just a few. The textbox would be very easy to implement, and used only when no predefined choice is suitable.

Comment: But you can do what you're proposing already. The outcome would be the same - there'd be a moderator flag that states "this belongs on X" - but the team would have had to write more code and maintain that code in the future.

Comment: OK, makes sense. I just believe my OCD is getting worst ;) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I lold.  I just found it today, too.

Flag for mod, "belongs on code review" and we'll migrate if appropriate.

Which brings up a question... how do we know? A code review question is pretty much on topic for both sites.

Comment: According to some of the close comments at Code Review, it belongs on Code Review if it's sharing code in order to get feedback on the code itself. For "disciplines, practices, and tools" for code reviews, it belongs on Programmers. And if it's a question that's just about an element of code such as why something works or what some code means, that should stay on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I disagree, there are things that only belong on `so`, `programmers` and `codereview` with little to no overlap most of the time. Letting the community migrate stuff automatically would be the best option.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Part of the problem is that *lots* of people don't understand that [codereview.se] isn't for debugging.  We get lots of flags to migrate to CR, most of which are flat out wrong.  So adding it to the list would just annoy CR users/mods.

Comment: @Won't: Not unlike the Programmers migration path.