# Provide more options for non moderator users when choosing off topic vote to close option

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, migration, vote-to-close

Some times I encounter a question that belong to other SE sites, but, when I want vote the question for off topic, I only can choose meta.SE.com for that question (I know I can flag question for moderator).

I think it's better provide list of other SE site for non-moderator user so that they can vote for migration of question to a related site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need option "belongs to CodeReview" in "close because off-topic" button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76675/need-option-belongs-to-codereview-in-close-because-off-topic-button)

Comment: @George I didn't any good answer on that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two criteria for a site to be eligible to migrate a question to:

1. they're only going to maintain the top *n* possibilities as places to migrate questions to.  It's done by what is 'most likely' to be migrated (for instance, it's far more likely for a post about soft-programmers stuff to be asked here than it is for gaming development stuff).
2. The site must be out of beta.

Until that changes, closing it as off topic and flagging it for a moderator are your best bets.

Comment: Unless Jeff changes his mind *n* will only ever be 4 as the there are 5 spots on the menu and the top one is always the site's meta.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76675/need-option-belongs-to-codereview-in-close-because-off-topic-button) for reasons why this probably won't happen, and for what to do instead.