# It would be nice to have an off-topic link to careers.stackoverflow.com when flagging

Tags: feature-request

I was just editing a new question in SO and tagged it with career-development, which I see is now considered off-topic in SO.

However, when I flagged it as off topic, there's no way to point it to careers.stackoverflow.com, which where I assume it needs to go.

Comment: Careers.stackoverflow.com is not a Q&A site

Comment: Next time I will actually look at the web site before suggesting it be used. And I just realized that there is default option on off topic; I had always picked a site previously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really any advantage in being able to mark posts as belonging on careers that is not already covered in the generic "off-topic" flag. It can't be moved there (as it's not a Q&A site) and I certainly can't imagine anyone editing someones CV to include or change whatever is in the post.

If anything I'd suggesting adding a comment to the original question stating that it is off-topic and that perhaps the poster might considering backing the [IT Careers & Training](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12887/it-careers-training) or [Professional Careers & Advice](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24003/professional-careers-advice) area 51 proposals.

Answer (score 4):

[careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is actually a job listing and resume/CV hosting site, not Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77587/154443) on options provided for off-topic migration.

Suffice it to say that even if careers were an appropriate place to send it, it's not going to get on the shortlist.