# Options in “vote as off-topic” dialog should include codereview.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need option “belongs to CodeReview” in “close because off-topic” button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76675/need-option-belongs-to-codereview-in-close-because-off-topic-button)

The options in the “vote as off-topic” dialog should include [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Flag for moderator review and suggest the migration... If there's enough demand, it'll get added to the UI.

Comment: See [Need option "belongs to CodeReview" in "close because off-topic" button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76675/need-option-belongs-to-codereview-in-close-because-off-topic-button). There's a hard limit of 5 migration destinations, one of which is always the site's Meta. So to open up one for Code Review, it needs to be a destination that is more prevalent than at least one of the other 4 options. Until then, you can always flag it for moderator attention, as they can migrate there.

Comment: For reference: [How is this site different from StackOverflow?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-is-this-site-different-from-stackoverflow)

Comment: Surely the obvious course of action would be to remove that dumb hard limit of 5?