# Make it easier to use Code Review as a chocolate bar burial facility

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, migration-path-request

For questions that are off-topic for Stack Overflow, 3K users can vote to close them as belonging on several Stack Exchanges, but not to the Code Review one. Can this be made a possibility?

Knowing that a question won't be going to Silicon Heaven, but instead will undergo silicon reincarnation, makes voting to close a question less unpleasant.

For those curious about "chocolate bar burial facility": six years ago, 3 million chocolate bars were crushed and buried in a 25-metre pit at Lucas Heights, otherwise best known as the location of Australia's only nuclear reactor. [Mars: crushed and buried](http://www.smh.com.au/news/national/mars-crushed-and-buried/2005/07/08/1120704538625.html)

[image: A truckload of chocolate ... literally! Mmm ... chocolate]

Comment: +1 for title alone. Man, I wish more sites were used for that purpose instead of being [toilet bowls](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Or a [trash bin](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/serverfault-com-is-not-your-trash-bin).

Comment: This seems to actually be a popular migration path request these days. See [Need option "belongs to CodeReview" in "close because off-topic" button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76675/need-option-belongs-to-codereview-in-close-because-off-topic-button) and [Options in Vote as Off Topic Dialog should include Code Review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80526/options-in-vote-as-off-topic-dialog-should-include-codereview-stackexchange-com).

Comment: "Until today the bars have been stored at a secret location under the protection of laser beam security."  Holy crap, Australia must be overrun with fatties and premenstrual women. *(if anybody can figure out a way to keep this comment funny yet less offensive pls let me know)*

Comment: @Will: Australia is sometimes described as one of the most obese developed countries, so maybe the first part is true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate to codereview as a voting option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123930/migrate-to-codereview-as-a-voting-option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only 5 blessed migration slots, of which 1 is dedicated to meta.

Can you make a case that these Code Review questions are more prevalent than one of the other 4, and should displace it in the list? Do you have data to support this, in the form of a giant list of closed questions that belonged on {x} site?

If not, then no -- flag them for moderator attention instead.

I am also disinclined to randomly migrate questions unless they are of *extremely* high quality.

Comment: I think it's more deserving of a slot than webmasters, as that's only one of many applications of programming.

Comment: @andrew the change isn't going to be made without data supporting it

Comment: I've [asked for data](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81103/what-are-the-most-common-migration-destinations-for-stack-overflow-questions), and Code Review being a blessed migration slot isn't justified. Yet.

Comment: Five slots?  Is that a technical barrier of some sort? :/

Comment: @robert it is a "Don't Make Me Think" barrier; we don't want to present closers with a list of 12 different destinations and make them suss out which one is correct. There should be 4 most frequently correct destinations + meta. If you believe a pet site deserves a place in that list, prove it with data of existing closed questions, not blue sky "what if there were.." imagineering.