# What are the most common migration destinations for Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration

What are the most common migration destinations for Stack Overflow questions?

**Background:** There currently doesn't seem to be [hard data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80964/make-it-easier-to-use-code-review-as-a-chocolate-bar-burial-facility) on the most common migration destinations of Stack Overflow questions, which is relevant to what sites deserve the top five "blessed" slots of "belongs on ...".

I'm not allowed to offer any bribes, but there's nothing in the rules stopping me posting a picture of a truckload of chocolate:

[image: Mmm ... chocolate]

Comment: this is available to diamond mods under `/admin/posts/migrated`

Comment: @Jeff - the link is actually `/admin/posts/migrated/away` for questions leaving. Given than 10K users can see the imported questions is there any reason they can't see the exported ones as well?

Comment: It makes perfect sense that the most common sites will be the sites *in* the dialog currently.  While moderators can migrate anywhere if they see the post / it gets flagged, chances are good that questions are just being closed as off-topic, which data explorer queries looking at migrations won't pick up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this hack of a script](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1047/post-migration-summary) that I just created on the Data Explorer

These are the top 5 migration sites out of Stack Overflow:

- Super User (354)
- Programmers.SE (265)
- Server Fault (182)
- WebMasters.SE (68)
- MetaStackOverflow (53)

I wouldn't be surprised if it is wrong though ;)

Comment: It vaguely looks like a "long tail" curve. Based on the results, there's nothing that isn't exclusionary in the top 10 apart from SU, programmers, SF and MSO, so webmasters is as good as any.

Answer (score 4):

The most common destinations are going to be those sites that are currently on the dialog namely:

- Here (Meta Stack Overflow)
- Super User
- Server Fault
- Programmers'
- Web masters

I'd say the most common are Super User and Server Fault - if only for historical reasons.

Now that moderators can migrate anywhere you can check on the destination sites (assuming you have access to the tools menu) to see where recent imports have come from - https://stackoverflow.com/tools/recently-imported.

A sortable, searchable list of recently exported questions would be what you would ideally need to work this out.

Comment: How is this calculated?  Could it be that those are the most common destinations _because_ they're on the dialog?

Comment: @MooingDuck - I did (sort of) point that out.

Answer (score 0):

May be search like this in google, and count?

```
site:superuser.com "migrated from stackoverflow.com"
site:serverfault.com "migrated from stackoverflow.com"
site:meta.stackoverflow.com "migrated from stackoverflow.com"

site:somestackexchangesite.com "migrated from stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: Google doesn't index all of the trilogy's questions.

Comment: That we _know_ is biased towards the questions already on teh dialog.