# Is the dumping-ground tag necessary and/or useful, or just political?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Re: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dumping-ground

I don't have a proposal to make it better or get rid of it, but it rubs me the wrong way.  My gut reaction is that it's just noise - at best a way to emphasize particular feelings some may have towards poor migration practices.

Is it a reasonable and viable tag?  Does it improve our ability to categorize, find, and deal with the questions and discussions we have on meta?

There are only 5 questions tagged as such, but over half happened in the last week, and I'd rather see it dealt with early on in it's life, rather than waiting and causing more of a ruckus than need be.

Comment: Actually, Andrew Grimm added that tag to all the questions you see with that tag only 3 hours ago. He may even have made it, but the site doesn't tell that.

Comment: Adam Davis!?!?!

Comment: Humph...Well if you're going to have a `dumping-ground` tag, it better be applied to [this question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Comment: @Robert: I can't believe I missed that one!

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, that's a pretty blatantly editorializing tag.

[migration](/questions/tagged/migration) is more than sufficient for the topic, already exists, and is found on many of those posts already.

It has been destroyed*.

<sub>*It may still linger in caches for a bit.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As @BoltClock noted, I created the tag.

I myself am in favor of aggressively migrating questions, and letting the recipient community judge the suitability of the questions. However, others disagree, and I decided I may as well tag the similar complaints together, so that the same arguments don't get repeated over and over again.

In addition, I like the meme, as could be guessed from my question [Make it easier to use Code Review as a chocolate bar burial facility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80964/make-it-easier-to-use-code-review-as-a-chocolate-bar-burial-facility).

Then again, I do lots of crazy things. Thanks for mentioning why you don't like the tag.