# Are there precedents to migrate a post to a beta site?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

Before I ask this question, I've read

- [Flagging questions for migration to a beta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115633/flagging-questions-for-migration-to-a-beta-site)
- [Make it easier to use Code Review as a chocolate bar burial facility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80964/make-it-easier-to-use-code-review-as-a-chocolate-bar-burial-facility)

but think they are not clear to me.

Because of the quality of answers, I flagged an closed question on SO and suggested to migrate to [Code Review beta](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

- [What's wrong with my quick sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141380/whats-wrong-with-my-quick-sort)

the flagging is responded with `helpful` and the question is then reopened, so I'm wondering will it really migrate to the beta site Code Review?

Comment: The default is to handle flags as "helpful", on the logic that lots of flagging should be encouraged.

Comment: Migration to beta sites happens all the time. I've flagged dozens of question for migration to crypto.SE, and most of them have been migrated.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I flagged a question on SO that was closed for being off-topic (since it was asking for a library recommendation) and asked that it be migrated to Software Recs, and got the following response: "declined - We're not currently migrating questions there while it's under beta."

Comment: @pacoverflow For beta sites which already worked out their identity pretty well mods are less resistant to migrations. Software recommendations is a rather experimental site which still needs to figure out what it's scope and rules are. In addition it has a similar problem as programmers.se, many SO user's will flag questions for migration even if they don't fulfill the rules of the target site because they don't understand those rules.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Moderators can migrate a question anywhere in the network, including public beta sites. Migrating to beta sites isn't something we encourage because beta should be all about a site figuring out its own voice rather than getting questions from elsewhere, but an occasional migration doesn't hurt much.

In this specific case, I think you missed the mark a bit with your flag. Code Review is all about taking *working* code and making improvements to it for style, speed, etc. The question you flagged opens with the following (emphasis mine):

> This early morning I wrote a quick sort using c#, but *it didn't work*. Can anyone view my code and give me some suggestions?
>
> *The result showed that it just moved some elements to the first half, but most of the elements were in the same place.*

So, the code is broken and the right place for the question is on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Good insightful answer, thanks!

Comment: As an example, a lot of telecoms questions get closed, not because they are poor questions but because they're off topic.  Some more are probably off topic, but slip under the radar on SO. If - hopefully - we get a SE telecoms beta site, they would fit nicely there.  There's clearly a demand for a telecoms/protocols/connectivity kind of site.  I don't see that it hurts the new site to have questioners kindly redirected away from SO - they've got the right voice, they're just in the wrong place.

Comment: @SList Swarming a new site with potentially old questions whose askers have moved on doesn't help a beta site. It mostly just drowns out new questions posted there and skews voting and reputation. If I recall right, there are a couple telecom/telephony type proposals in Area 51 right now. If they become actual sites, they'll be given time for the people who are active there already to build them up... and if some newly posted questions get migrated there from Stack Overflow, that's fine.

Comment: Anna, moving old questions wholesale is not what I meant. I was talking about moving new SO questions onto the telecoms site. There is a fairly steady stream of suitable ones.  At the moment they are closed before people can see and answer them.

Comment: @SList Right now we don't have a telecoms site. When we do, new questions posted on Stack Overflow can and will be evaluated for migration on their own merit.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said :-)

Comment: @SList Fantastic. I'm glad we had this chance to repeat the same point at each other. :)