# Should beta-sites be listed for migration suggestions?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, flags

I wanted to flag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295576/reverse-engineering-concerns) as candidate to be migrated to [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/). I guess the question title obiously qualifies to suggest this site. Also I think, suggesting questions to be migrated to beta sites would be cool, since it would fill the site with content it badly needs to leave the beta stage.

Is there any reason, why beta sites are not listed in the suggestions (except they are beta sites)?

Edit: The question is about why they are not or if beta sites should be listed, not about what to do with this question. As other questions suggest, I've flagged this question as *Needs moderator attention* > *Other...*.

Comment: Relevant, if not a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90061/should-questions-that-belong-to-public-beta-sites-be-moved-there as well as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169983/are-there-precedents-to-migrate-a-post-to-a-beta-site

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm stealing Tim Post's answer from a [related question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5780/25936) on Meta Programmers:

> we don't establish migration paths to a site that is still in its beta period. We don't want to send content from one site to another unless we're certain that the target site is a permanent fixture. There are exceptions to this; moderators can migrate relatively new questions to sites not in the current migration path, but this ability should be used sparingly. A question should be of much better than average quality, and all hope of it being on topic for the current site should be exhausted prior to going around the established routes.

Also, beta sites need to make it on their own and prove to their communities and to SE that they are viable. Getting flooded with questions - especially answered ones - from a larger site doesn't really help. The total questions counter may go up, but... who cares? The beta community needs to generate quality content and attract experts on their own, if they are interested in graduating.

Lastly, that question is... not a real one. I get that you don't want to discuss the question specifically, but if that's the kind of questions we'd be sending to a Reverse Engineering, that's a good enough reason to never make it a migration target, even when it graduates. Migrations should be beneficial to the target site, not [turn it into a toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl).

Comment: convinced me! :)