# Add text to the “close as off-topic” dialog explaining the possibility of flagging for moderator attention

Tags: feature-request, migration, vote-to-close, off-topic

In [“Need option “belongs to CodeReview” in “close because off-topic” button”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76675/need-option-belongs-to-codereview-in-close-because-off-topic-button), it was explained that

> If you see a question that you think would be a better fit for another site not on the migration list flag it for moderator attention explaining where you think it should go.

I didn’t think of that. I think most people won’t think of that. The “close as off-topic” dialog should contain some text to this effect to highlight the possibility.