# How do I migrate a question to a site which is not listed in close window?

Tags: support, migration, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move to *any* site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86928/move-to-any-site)
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

When I select Off topic option in Vote to close it shows only few options. I know that this question belong to [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

How can I select that option to tell the OP to ask there?

The close window shows the below options:

- Meta Stack Overflow
- Server Fault
- Super User
- Tex Stack Exchange
- DBA Stack Exchange

How to add other option?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't. Close it as off-topic & then Flag -> It needs Moderator attention -> Mention where it should be migrated