# Let us migrate to *any* site in the network

Tags: feature-request, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move to *any* site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86928/move-to-any-site)
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

See also [this recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140372/167210).

(I wouldn't be at all surprised if this is a duplicate, but I didn't find a match.)

Currently, if I vote to close an off-topic question on StackOverflow, I have the option of recommending migration to any of 5 other sites, currently:

- meta.stackoverflow.com
- serverfault.com
- superuser.com
- tex.stackexchange.com
- dba.stackexchange.com

I often want to migrate to a site not on the list, such as programmers, unix, or askubuntu.

I know I can flag a question for moderator attention (and that's what I usually do), but why not permit migration to *any* site?

I'm not suggesting expanding the current 5-item list to 87 (at last count). Just keep the current 5-item list of the most common migration targets, and add an option to bring up a list of all sites. (I'm sure there are more convenient methods than just a list; I'll leave that to you guys to design it.)

Comment: Sathya has already given a good answer for it, in that question.

Comment: @Lucifer: That's the current workaround. I'm asking for a new feature that lets me specify the target site directly -- without requiring manual intervention by a moderator.

Comment: From what I've read here on MSO, the idea behind the restriction seems to be that users often don't know the site they recommend as a migration target well enough to be sure it's on-topic there, resulting in lots of rejected migrations (I think Programmers SE was a particularly bad case, hence its removal from the list).

Comment: @Bart: Would keeping the current 5-item list and not-quite-hiding the full list behind it address this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move to *any* site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86928/move-to-any-site) and [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites)

Answer (score 11):

Moderators have exactly the tool you describe, a text field with autocomplete for all sites in the network. Not providing this tool to the general public is an intentional decision by SE.

[image]

The overall experience with migration is that the feature is often used wrong, migrating a question is the nicer alternative to just closing, and many users would rather do the nice thing instead of just closing a question. This often leads to bad migrations of questions that should have been closed anywhere. Users are also often not aware of the exact scope of the target site, and this problem gets considerably worse once you include the not-so-related sites in the migration option.

It might sound nice in theory, but migration is a problematic and often misused feature. Making even more migration options available to all users is not necessarily a good idea.