# Move SO question to Patents

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move to *any* site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86928/move-to-any-site)
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)
>   [How do I migrate a question to a site which is not listed in close window?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140372/how-do-i-migrate-a-question-to-a-site-which-is-not-listed-in-close-window)

Is possible to vote to move a SO question to [Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/)? (or to any other SE site, not listed among 5 off-topic alternatives)

Comment: The typical answer is "just flag for a diamond moderator, they can move from anywhere to anywhere," but what question are you thinking of? I know some crazy off-topic gets posted sometimes, but even so, SO -> Patents seems like a _weird_ migration to me.

Comment: @PopularDemand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635155/unicode-license

Comment: Licenses is not the topic for Patents.

Comment: If not Patents, where the question possibly can be answered?

Comment: I don't recall there are sites about licenses. Programmers has some questions about software licenses, but I cannot tell you they consider those questions still on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can flag for moderation attention, and ask for a question to be migrated.
Bear in mind that old questions are not probably migrated; in the same way, questions that are not good are not migrated (e.g. subjective questions).

For *Ask Patents*, remember the topic is:

- Solicit help finding prior art that might apply to a patent or application
- Get answers to hard questions about specific patents
- Ask questions about the US patent system or process