# How to select a different Stack Exchange site while flagging a question for migration?

Tags: feature-request, support

I wanted to flag a question for migration to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about), but there were only Meta Stack Overflow, Super User, [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/about), [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/about) and [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/about) in the list.

Maybe it's a good idea to add an autocomplete field (or something) to enter other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move to \*any\* site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86928/212576)

Comment: @hjpotter92 And about half of all other Meta questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `flag > moderator attention > other` and in the description text-box, put the reason like "It would be suitable for Server Fault" etc.

Comment: It's definitely solution but if there are some many questions why not implement such a simple request?

Comment: @twil Tim Post explains it quite well [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86950/212576).

Comment: I'm not quite agreed (with votes system and all) but it definitely an answer now