# What to do when site to migrate to isn't one of the options

Tags: support, migration, off-topic

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009478/how-do-i-mod-a-flip-phone) clearly belongs on android.stackexchange.com However when voting to close, under Off Topics > This Question Belongs on Another Stack Exchange Network, there is no option for android.stackexchange.

[image: screen shot]

UPDATE: as pointed out the cited question isn't actually about an Android Phone (it's from the pre-smartphone era) but I'll leave this question here on meta as it still may be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

If a migration path has been set up for that particular site, then choose the option "*This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*", upon which you'll see a list of possibilities (all the sites for which migration paths have been set up) and can then vote to migrate the question thataways.

If not, just vote to close as off-topic and flag the question for moderator attention. Moderators on one site can migrate questions to any other site in the SE network.

See also:

- [When voting to migrate an off-topic question, why is the list of sites limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited)
- [Migrate to *any* site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86928/migrate-to-any-site)