# Why is the migration from Stack Overflow only allowed to those specific sites?

Tags: feature-request, questions, vote-to-close, migration, close-reasons

Why is the migration from Stack Overflow only allowed to  those specific sites?

> [image: screenshot]

Yes, these sites are closer to programming, but IMHO, *TeX - LaTeX* and *SharePoint* are rarely used; for example, the *Server Fault*, *Programmers*, *Code Review* are the better options to choose.

Maybe this list should be a read from the user's preferences.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150206/regarding-the-high-number-of-rejected-migrations-from-stack-overflow-to-server-f - Server Fault used to be in there, but we, collectively, suck at migrations. It was removed. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators - same thing for Programmers, horrid migrations.

Comment: Sigh. If we're lucky, this only gets feature-requested once a week. We were not so lucky this week, this is at least request #2. I'm voting to close as the canonical duplicate, not because you're asking exactly the same thing, but because all of the questions that *are* exact duplicates are closed as duplicates of that one.

Comment: `Sharepoint - 127 - 1% rejected` - I hope that it was not the main reason to include the site to this list :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76675/need-option-belongs-to-codereview-in-close-because-off-topic-button - that's the dup for Code Review (no user migrations to betas).

Comment: Or this one, @Mat: [Can we add Code Review to the migration list?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191347)

Comment: Or that one, or one of the others indeed @Cody.