# Migrate question that are off-topic but has many votes

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic

I would like to migrate [Mac Virtualization: VM Ware Fusion or Parallels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156/mac-virtualization-vm-ware-fusion-or-parallels) that is clearly off-topic on StackOverflow.com even though it has many upvotes and an accepted answer.

I have already flagged the question today, but it was dismissed by the moderators. In my point of view it should be migrated to http://Apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we receive a flag on an old question, we typically ask the moderators of the target site if migrating it would be appropriate. A question might not get migrated because:

- It is too old, and duplicates existing content
- It is a 'list of' or 'what's best' question, or otherwise too subjective to send

Additionally, we don't typically migrate 'famous' questions to sites that are not yet out of beta. While most SE sites do eventually launch, there is always the possibility that they might run out of steam. I realize that the Apple SE site has launched, I'm just listing reasons why we might decide not to send it.

We do appreciate the flags that help churn these up to the top so that they get attention, but we can't always subsequently migrate them.

An example of why we're rather cautious can be seen in the [toilet bowl incident](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl).

Comment: Thanks, that make sense. But in this case I don't really understood why the flag was dismissed and I got flag penalty.

Comment: @Jonas - I'm thinking that was just a mistake. If a question does look like it belongs on another site, I always dismiss the flag as valid (even if it doesn't get migrated for other reasons).