# Most viewed questions against the rules on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, rules

I don't know how much I have to elaborate on this. As the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) says:

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site [...]

The faq is pretty straightforward what is considered a good question and what isn't. Despite this when I look at the [questions with the most upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes), 90% of them are exactly like that. Most of the time they violate *more than one* principle which is exemplified right after the rule itself.

Is the cause:

- Poor moderation? (Users with enough privileges do not care abut this rule?)
- Wrong incentives? (A question like this can get you 3 gold 3 silver 3 bronze medals if survives moderation.)
- Or anything else? (No idea.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because if you look at the dates they were posted, you'll notice that they are all quite old. They were all posted when the rules were not quite enforced as strictly as they are now and are sort of "grandfathered in".

See: [Should old off-topic posts be migrated, and under what criteria?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80272/should-old-off-topic-posts-be-migrated-and-under-what-criteria/80536#80536) and [Disposing of old questions that are now off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82349/disposing-of-old-questions-that-are-now-off-topic)