# Should all questions related to Scrum and Agile tags be migrated from SO to Programmers-SE?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, migration, software-engineering-se

I noticed that many questions related to Scrum, Agile and other related tags are often closed on Stack Overflow as off-topic and migrated to programmers.stacexchange. Should we simply migrate whole these tags to programmers.stackexchange? I don't see too much point in having half of questions on SO and half of questions on programmers-SE. Also it would be nice to somehow notify users when asking new questions with these tags that they should ask it on programmers instead.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82349/disposing-of-old-questions-that-are-now-off-topic/82355#82355

Comment: This is more about migrating whole tags with their questions so that tag "doesn't exist" in SO. If new Q/A sites are created for special topics why not migrate related content to that sites?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm against wholesale migration of questions from one site to another (regardless of the sites involved). As I explained in my answer linked to by marcog **each question must be judged on it's own merits**.

A wholesale migration would migrate bad questions along with the good as well as inappropriate questions that were badly tagged. *Closed questions could be ignored, so they're not an issue.*

Comment: And there are mixed-tag questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

**No,** it is not that easy, as a question may include how to write unit tests etc

Comment: If it is about "how to write unit tests" instead of "how to write unit test for this method" then it still suitable for programmers.SE.

Answer (score 0):

[Similar and more general question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84249/when-will-so-become-irrelevant) was asked today. Responses provided in that question answer my question as well.