# Which questions should be on-topic on Drupal Answers, but not on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, stack-exchange

[*Drupal Answers*](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) is the Q&A site about Drupal, but which of the questions about Drupal are on-topic on *Stack Overflow*, and then be asked on both the places?

As *Stack Overflow* is a programming Q&A, I would expect that any question related to how to use a module, which module to choose, which Drupal version to choose, should not be on-topic on *Stack Overflow*.

Once *Drupal Answers* is not a beta anymore, would Drupal questions be still accepted on *Stack Overflow*?

Comment: Also see: [When will SO become irrelevant?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84249/when-will-so-become-irrelevant) (For the record, I'm sort of against the trend of unnecessary specialization. I can't imagine why we needed to extract Sharepoint and Drupal questions from SO proper.)

Comment: @Code Gray Some Drupal questions are not about programming at all; I think that in a programming site, to answer on which settings a module exposes in its user interface could be considered off-topic as it is not about programming at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they're still on-topic for Stack Overflow. Just because a more specific site exists does not make them suddenly off-topic on the more general site.

This very same question has been discussed before when other, more targeted sites made it out of beta. For example, questions that *could* be asked on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) are still considered to be on-topic on Super User.

Of course, it's reasonable for users to leave comments suggesting that a question may be better asked on the focused site, in order to receive better answers. And it's perfectly appropriate to flag questions to be migrated directly there by a moderator, if you think they'd truly be a better fit. That decision is probably best made on a case-by-case basis by users who are knowledgeable about the topic areas.

Although it is worth noting that asking a question on several SE sites at a time is [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80216/can-i-ask-the-same-question-on-more-than-one-stack-exchange-site).

Comment: I disagree with the notion that a programming question specific to Drupal should be allowed to be posted on SO, while at the same time crossposting is strongly discouraged and often quickly called out. If the question is specific to a CMS that has a SE, why bother creating the separate SE if you can't trust where to find answers or post questions?

I constantly try to ask my Drupal questions on the Drupal SE, but the community has felt like it's been withering on the vine since I got into it 3 years ago.

Comment: @slake The point is that Stack Overflow cannot (should not) *refuse* to accept a question that is, according to its own standards, completely on-topic, just because there exists another Stack Exchange site on which it would *also* be on topic. Please do not misconstrue my answer to suggest that you should prefer to ask Drupal questions on Stack Overflow instead of on Drupal.SE. Indeed, Drupal.SE would probably (*should* probably, I have no idea, I don't participate there, and you suggest it is "withering on the vine") be a better place to ask the question than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Aside from that, I'm not really sure what your point is. If you are asking me why we have created multiple Stack Exchange sites with redundant, overlapping purviews, I honestly have no idea. I wondered the same thing *years* ago when we first started doing it. There was a big discussion about it on the [global Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/); you can probably do a search there and find some of the questions, if you have some time to kill. But I didn't get an answer that was particularly satisfying. Something about "building communities." It remains unclear why tags can't be a community.