# Should questions that belong to Public Beta sites be moved there?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, migration

I see lots of questions about Drupal, and [there is a SE site for Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/).

**Should I flag those questions to be moved there?**

Comment: Also see: [Which questions should be on-topic on Drupal Answers, but not on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87719/which-questions-should-be-on-topic-on-drupal-answers-but-not-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Grey area.  I usually migrate without hesitation.

Comment: I know Jeff has said to only migrate to beta sites under exceptional circumstances, but the only reference I can find is [this](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167/since-questions-wont-necessarily-get-migrated-here-can-we-copy-them/168#168). I thought there was something on *this* meta, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a *new* question, and it's *off-topic* on Stack Overflow, and you're *pretty sure* it's on-topic on the target site, then vote to close and flag to request a migration.

If it's an old question, don't bother unless you're a regular on the target site and you're thinking “we (target) want it from them (SO)”, not “they (target) want it from us (SO)”.

Answer (score 2):

Beta sites might be deleted in the future, and I think that is the reason why migration there is disabled.
But in my opinion, it should be enabled.

Comment: There are only 5 destinations on the migrate dialog, so it's highly unlikely that Drupal will be added even if the site leaves public beta.

Comment: It's not disabled. It is discouraged in part for the reason you mention, but it's available to moderators. Like ChrisF said, it's unlikely to ever be enabled as a community-driven migration path due to the lack of space on the migration dialog.