# Are Drupal questions off-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which questions should be on-topic on Drupal Answers, but not on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87719/which-questions-should-be-on-topic-on-drupal-answers-but-not-on-stack-overflow)

Should we close Drupal questions as off-topic (like we are closing question as off-topic which are about servers) since there is [dedicated (sister) website](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) for Drupal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the questions are programming questions, they should remain open.

That there is a dedicated site for the topic doesn't make it less on-topic. However, if you believe that a question would actually have a better chance to be answered on the dedicated site over SO, flag for moderators and ask for migration.