# Stack Overflow and Drupal Answers

Tags: discussion

There are [nearly 12,000 questions tagged "Drupal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal) on Stack Overflow (that's nearly half the total number of questions on Drupal-specific Stack Exchange [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/))! Most questions seem to be about how to do things in the workflow of Drupal.  For example

- [Drupal 7: Filtering Menu Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832784/drupal-7-filtering-menu-links)
- [Drupal Custom Menu Positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312218/drupal-custom-menu-positioning)
- [Drupal Search in Block View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574105/drupal-search-in-block-view)
- ... etc.

Stack Exchange FAQ states Stack Overflow is for:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers
- practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

I do think there is room for coding-specific Drupal questions on Stack Overflow, but it seems like a lot of the existing questions on Stack Overflow are about Drupal as a CMS rather than Drupal as a system to code in.

I'm not sure what the fix is, but should most questions tagged "Drupal" be migrated to Drupal Answers?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87719/which-questions-should-be-on-topic-on-drupal-answers-but-not-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

No, as we've stated many times before, **just because it's on-topic on another site doesn't mean it should be migrated**. We migrate questions because they're *off-topic here* and *would be on-topic there*.

Your best bet is more advertising for your Drupal-specific site. If you see questions not gathering answers or do not belong on Stack Overflow, post a comment directing the user to Drupal Answers and suggest that they may get answers there.

If users prefer to go to Stack Overflow to get their answers, and their questions are on-topic, we should not be forcing them to go elsewhere.

Comment: Edited question to emphasize that my concern is not about generating traffic to "your (?) Drupal-specific site".  Rather, there's tons of off-topic Drupal questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If they're off-topic then vote to close or flag to close like any other question. If they *can* be migrated, use the other option to indicate that they;d be acceptable on Drupal Answers. A lot of these questions, however, could have existed before Drupal Answers and most are simply too old to migrate anyways. Not even moderators could migrate them.