# Should MSE related questions be allowed on independent meta.SE sites?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which meta am I supposed to post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on)

Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the core Stack Exchange engine that powers [all Stack Exchange websites](http://www.stackexchange.com/sites) are asked on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/faq).

I have seen many questions (above 30 ) on http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com which are already present on http://meta.stackoverflow.com . 
e.g

1. [How to format a link in a comment?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/661/how-to-format-a-link-in-a-comment)
2. [Check number of posts edited](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/check-number-of-posts-edited)

This questions nothing to do with Meta.movies . [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) says question related to http://movies.stackexchange.com are allowed only.

- Then why do we allow these type of questions on independent meta sites ?
- Shouldn't we delete or migrate this questions to http://meta.stackexchange.com.
- Should we flag this type of questions for deletion or migration?

This is problem with every independent meta sites. Many people don't know MSO but know specific meta sites. So raising question on specific meta. I am confused what should be done in such cases.

See also reference [Should MSO related questions allowed on this meta?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/780/should-mso-related-questions-allowed-on-this-meta)

Comment: I have asked over there :P. Moderators thinks that it's OK to have duplication of meta questions to movies.meta. I have confused because of that answers that's why I am asking question :( @Bart

Comment: and should  **meta.se** related question allowed on **meta2.se**  
_____and should  **meta2.se** related question allowed on **meta3.se** _____
and should  **meta3.se** related question allowed on **meta4.se** 
_____and should  **meta4.se** related question allowed on **meta5.se**  
........and should  **metaN.se** related question allowed on **metaN+1.se**

Comment: Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the core Stack Exchange engine are allowed on any meta. For more traffic ask it on MSO. If it's specific site question ask it on specific meta. @NullPointer