# Should rep earned on the main site carry over to its relative meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, per-site-meta

I feel that it is a bit unfair that rep doesn't carry over between the parent site and its meta. This is the case for every single one of the sites I've been a part in on the Stack Exchange Network. It makes little sense for someone with 5k+ rep to come to its site's meta and have just 1 rep. I know that at least some sites have rep being shared the other way around (meta->parent), but the fact that 0 rep whatsoever is shared from parent to meta seems somewhat illogical to me.

Comment: I made it more generalized because it isn't specific to SO. I see it on Code Golf, Super User, Server Fault, and some others as well.

Comment: I don't follow, this **is** the case everywhere but Stack Overflow and  Meta Stack Overflow - the rest of the network already carries rep to the meta.  Meta Stack Overflow will also do this soon.

Comment: Ummm, what makes you think this? Please link me to a profile with some rep on the parent site and 1 rep on meta.

Comment: Never mind. Question answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On *every* site except for Stack Overflow, rep is shared from parent user (main site) to their respective per-site meta user.

*However*, [Meta Stack Overflow is a little different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89232/237685). It's not a normal per-site meta, it's kinda like a capital of Stack Exchange. Thus, rep is independent of any Stack Exchange site you are active on. You earn your own rep here. However, [this will soon change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own). Meta Stack Overflow will soon be a per-site meta only for Stack Overflow, and Meta Stack Exchange will take the role of being the capital.

Comment: Ok. That wasn't the case until recently, but it's been a while since I've been on a meta.

Comment: No, [this is the way per-site metas have _always_ been](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1255/how-does-the-reputation-on-parent-and-on-meta-site-work), @impinball.

Comment: ok. Maybe I was slightly oblivious then.