# When a new Stack Exchange site is opened, shouldn't related questions be moved to the new site automatically?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, migration, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should we migrate old questions to new SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76702/should-we-migrate-old-questions-to-new-se-sites)
>   [Should old off-topic posts be migrated, and under what criteria?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80272/should-old-off-topic-posts-be-migrated-and-under-what-criteria)
>   [Disposing of old questions that are now off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82349/disposing-of-old-questions-that-are-now-off-topic)

For example, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com has opened recently.

But on Stack Overflow, there is a lot of questions that are, for most part, related to this site.

Both for older questions, tagged with [sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint) and for new questions, shouldn't them be automatically moved to this new site (or at least suggested for new questions with such tag)?

I imagine it's not as easy as it seems, but maybe the idea is right ?

Comment: We don't like to migrate old questions to new sites. And there's also no point in migrating questions from SO that are already on topic there. New, *well-asked* questions can be migrated, however: flag them for moderator attention.

Comment: The real duplicate is [Should we migrate old questions to new SE sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76702/should-we-migrate-old-questions-to-new-se-sites) if it's about moving questions that are *not* on-topic on SO.

Answer (score 2):

The questions were and still are on-topic on the original site. There is no point of migrating question that are already answered unless they did not received a satisfactory answer.

Indeed it is tempting to migrate to push more content to the new site, but this would mess with the reputation of many users on the original site and generate lot of complains for something that is not worth it.

By the way, migration sometimes bring to new site answers that does not match the community way of doing things. Because of this, I will not recommend those migrations, so that the new site can forged it's own authority.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The related questions have already been answered, and do not need to be moved to another site to clutter it up. The new ones probably should, like @Cody Gray said so.