# Avoid tweeting bad questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, twitter

I realize that tweeting questions by @serverfault (and other SE twitter accounts) is automated, but shouldn't questions with close votes not be tweeted?

For example [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/340104/cpu-virtualization-technology-intel-vt-in-a-laptop) is way OT for SF and has 4 close votes at the time of this writing. It had (I believe) two close votes when it was tweeted.

[image]

I don't know what the algorithm for tweeting questions is, but this question wasn't highly voted, it was very new, it had close votes, and it's from a low-rep user. Maybe it's time to be a little more selective?

If my memory is failing me and this was tweeted before close votes, my premise still stands. The question is about 40 minutes old at the time of this writing and was tweeted about 4 minutes after it was asked. Shouldn't questions be given enough time to be vetted by the community before they're shouted to the twitter universe?

Comment: My subjective impression is that the algorithm is optimized for tweeting bad question just a minute before they are closed.

Comment: Could what is really happening here be that Tweeting the questions is causing the close votes, by virtue of the additional attention?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Even if that's the case, this question was tweeted when it was ~4 minutes old. Shouldn't the community be given the chance to close the crap before it gets tweeted?

Comment: In either case, it creates a bad impression for the site if bad questions are tweeted, not just because they're then closed but because they're bad questions, and therefore not a good advert for the site in the first place.

Comment: *Possibly* related: [Are the “greatest hits” in the Stack Overflow newsletter appropriate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102786)

Comment: related: [Avoid sharing bad questions at Facebook](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244189/165773)

Comment: -1 the closevotes might be wrong ...

Comment: @Dilaton sure, and so might downvotes or answers or upvotes. Why don't we do away with all of it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is now deployed...we won't tweet questions with close votes (with the exception of bounties, which we feel didn't need this check...they survived around long enough for the bounty to start).

Comment: Even with a single close vote? I've noticed at least on UX.SE a single close vote is reasonably easy to get. By the time you have 3 it's probably a bad question.

Comment: @Ben - Yes, even a single close vote...better to be safe here, since on some sites it's hard to even get 1 close vote, we'd rather err on the side of caution when publicizing content.

Comment: Makes sense, I don't really oppose it

Comment: Does it look at flags on the question as well? If not can it and not Tweet anything with a flag. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NickCraver: Yeah, what about flags?

Comment: You guys should probably also check out [this one here](http://meta.superuser.com/q/4772/48078) – wonder how that got tweeted.

Comment: What if the closevoters are wrong? At least on physics SE there is a bunch of closevoters and batch hunters who regularly overreaches their state of knowledge by going on a closevote spree against high-level technical questions they have no clue about. The bad impact of thouse people should not be amplified by making their bad capricious closevotes prevent that legitimate up to very good questions get shared ... I dont know if other sites know this problem too.

Comment: Why is that relevant here @Dilaton? If we assume what you say is true, then the problem is the capricious closevotes, not the tweet script. And that's a problem only the Physics.SE community can solve...

Comment: one (meta) question with a close vote [has been tweeted recently](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/7525/revisions) (not that I complain mind you:). Consider [edit]ing to clarify if this tweeting block doesn't include meta sites