# The Twitter bot should not Tweet posts that have flags on them

Tags: feature-request, twitter

While reviewing the flags on a Programmers post I found this:

[image: Bad Twitter bot]

You can clearly see that the post was flagged 5 minutes **before** the post was Tweeted. While in this case the post remains open, it might not have done and there would have been (another) closed question Tweeted to the world.

[Posts with close votes aren't Tweeted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115722/avoid-tweeting-bad-questions) so can the same logic be applied to posts with flags?

Yannis raises an interesting point in the comments - perhaps the number of helpful flags raised by the flagger should be taken into account as well. This would mean that a flag from someone with 300 helpful flags *will* stop the Tweet, while a flag from someone with only 10 won't.

Of course, once the flags have been cleared and if the post is still open then it should be eligible for Tweeting once again.

Comment: But then the twitter bot will have nothing to tweet about on P.SE... :)

Comment: @MarvinPinto I tend to agree with you, any single flag short circuiting a tweet is probably not what we want. But there is this very nice thingy that gives some of sort credibility to flags, if only I could remember how it was called...

Comment: @YannisRizos But in all seriousness, we really can't expect mods to _clear_ flags quickly enough for the twitter bot to matter. By that, I mean by the time the bot is finally _allowed_ to tweet something, the question won't be as _new_ anymore -- if that sort of thing matters at all (just spitballing).

Comment: @MarvinPinto Yes you really can't expect us to clear flags so quickly (hear that 10k+ users?). There is a very interesting thing though, both our [Marshals](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/badges/94/marshal) don't have the vote to close privilege, I'd say having 500 helpful flags is good enough to short circuit a tweet.

Comment: Perhaps the whole automated tweeting thing needs to be looked at as a whole per a [discussion on the Programmers Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/should-we-be-concerned-that-stackprogrammer-tweets-lead-to-closed-deleted-quest). I don't think questions that aren't representative of a community should be tweeted, so is there a better way to introduce human review of questions that are scheduled for being tweeted?

Comment: @ThomasOwens - I agree with that, but this will do as an interim measure.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, anything better than what we have now, that's for sure.

Comment: But the flaggings might not be genuine.