# Twitter bots share posts with closevotes on them

Tags: bug, status-completed, twitter

[Posts with close votes aren't supposed to be tweeted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115722/avoid-tweeting-bad-questions).

The @StackWorkplace feed just shared the post [Why not always feel confident enough to speak and share my views in workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/why-not-always-feel-confident-enough-to-speak-and-share-my-views-in-workplace) which had 3 closevotes [(and a flag)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124994/the-twitter-bot-should-not-tweet-posts-that-have-flags-on-them?lq=1). I got to the Tweet 2 minutes after it was posted so I really don't think all the votes were added after the tweet, especially since one comment states "I voted to close" 3 hours before the tweet.

I also suspect this (now deleted) post was tweeted after getting close votes: [Computer Science minor?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/computer-science-minor?atw=1) which I closed/deleted about an hour after it was tweeted, it also had close votes when I got to it.

The Twitter bot seems to be ignoring the check for close votes before tweeting questions.

Answer (score 6):

Technically the check was correct, *questions* with close votes weren't being tweeted.

However, answers on questions with close votes could be.  Looks like the same thing from the outside.

This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: So the bots weren't lying when they tweeted links calling them "Great answers".

Comment: Sure about that? The tweet shows up on the Q not answer, http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/2531/revisions and the post links directly to the question: https://twitter.com/stackworkplace/status/224498062154928128 , don't the answer-tweets say "Great Answer"?