# What changed in the Hot Questions sidebar algorithm?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

I've recently noticed that the hot questions list is now different almost every time I look at it. It used to be static - I.e. I could browse around for half an hour and the items on it would be minimally changed.

Was the algorithm changed? In what way?

Comment: Really? I honestly find they stick around for longer. There was at least one question that hung around for almost two weeks on my end.

Comment: This is actually a very recent change, like within 24 hrs of now if I'm correct, @Eric.

Comment: Fair enough, I haven't been online enough in the last 24h to know for sure. (I do hope they've changed it as it was *seriously* favoring sites like Code Golf; though, considering their decline in V/D, I can see that the algorithm has probably changed.)

Comment: dont think thats a desirable design feature that it seems somewhat random on every refresh.... apparently there are many hot questions to choose from, but how could that be? doesnt that sort of negate the unique status of hot questions?

Comment: @vzn 200 hottest questions, select 50 at random from that list. Out of tens of thousands of questions that still pretty hot but you don't see the same questions over and over (which is boring)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[The usual algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page/61343#61343) calculates a score, ranks the questions and then just pulls off the top few results.

We're testing an alternative method that calculates a score, ranks the questions and then pulls a somewhat larger number off the top, shuffles them, and stuff the top of the deck into the sidebar.

Since this is a test, not everyone will see this. Those who do will observe both a larger variety of questions, a less predictable order for those that do show up repeatedly *and* a greater chance of seeing different questions on different page-loads.

And since this is a test, it may end up having *horrible* side-effects that result in it being tied up in a sack with a brick, thrown off a bridge and never spoken of again.

Comment: A/B testing? (I don't see it, currently)

Comment: Yes, we are split testing, and Shog9 pretty much nailed it.

Comment: Yeah. If the list doesn't change every time you refresh the page, you're on the B team. Or maybe it's the A-Team. I forget whether or not Hannibal played cards.

Comment: If it doesn't work, will the employee(s) responsible also be put in said sack?

Comment: They'll be given a llama and told to pair-program with it.

Comment: does testing cover [per-site hot tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot "example - SO hot tab")?

Comment: This has no connection to what is shown in the hot/week/month tabs, which are site-specific.

Comment: ["Tina, you fat lard.. come get some jQuery."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2glOppqBRg)

Comment: I love this change oh-so-much. This is a much better way of getting exposure to other sites and definitely decreases the likelihood of a 40-year flood every few months compared to the previous system. Plus it shows you guys care about this issue, which is definitely awesome. Thanks Shog!

Comment: Don't thank me - I'm just the messenger. This is Jeremy & Jarrod's baby, @jmac!

Comment: Thank you Jeremy and @Jarrod!

Comment: I shoulda just credited Jon Skeet, since apparently it's his [implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm/1287572#1287572) of the shuffle algorithm at work here. And also, because there aren't enough J-names involved in this thread yet.

Comment: great experiment! To help in testing, I plan to [visit Stack Overflow questions in the hot list](http://stackexchange.com/questions) and _actively vote up_ posts I like. This way will let SE team study how effective it works against "lemming effect" using familiar material (instead of obscure questions at smaller sites like Programmers, Workplace, Math, Code Golf, UX)

Comment: This seems to have been shut off. I was rotating questions the past few days, but it seems the latest build(?) may have shut it off again for great sadness. Can we get a follow-up on why and future plans please?

Comment: So far as I'm aware, it's still running, @jmac - you may have ended up in a different group though. Remember, this is still a test, so it's important that some folks *don't* see it active some of the time. FWIW, the results have been... Not great so far: a significantly smaller number of people are clicking through to randomly-selected questions than to the top questions, which hints that the algorithm may've been doing a better job of identifying general-interest questions across topics than some expected.

Comment: Jeff wouldn't be surprised to find out that _completely_ dropping the algorithm turns out disappointing. Neither am I: _"bounty awarded for inventing formula that has been proven to work reasonably well in the past (and still does a fairly good job at early picking of potentially popular questions)"_ ([Feb 22 '13](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99077/dont-let-questions-stick-to-the-top-of-the-hot-questions-list-forever/164078#comment496917_101857 "quote source"))

Comment: @Shog9 Disappointing to hear it's not working out so well. I enjoyed quick access to a whole bunch of interesting questions from various sites this week. Now that I appear to be back in the control group, the list has returned to 1-2 good questions and a whole bunch of "meh" clogging up the slots for days on end.

Comment: Test isn't over yet - we'll see how it all hashes out in the end, @Troyen. There might be a happy medium here.

Comment: just a thought about _significantly smaller number of people are clicking through..._ maybe it's time to to decide whether number on clicks is so much more important than the kind of promoted content. After all, if SE team is so much into the racket of clicks, most natural direction would be to shift to porn/sex and dump the idea of attracting experts in sites topics; it's hardly a coincidence that recent _sticky top-hot_ question had sex in the title, otherwise being pretty mediocre

Comment: You're being absurd, @gnat. Is there any *point* to putting these things in the sidebar if folks aren't using them? I mean, I guess they're sorta *decorative*, but I can think of better ways to use the space. That said, clicks aren't everything - *answers* are up ever so slightly, which may be a good sign.

Comment: I am merely pointing that it's absurd to use number of clicks as the only criteria in the test. It is also absurd, up to the point of becoming totally kafkian to run that test without even getting an understanding of [what is the purpose of hot questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219922/165773). Given that, I am not surprised to see that you consider answers-up as a good sign...

Comment: ... (hint: per my studies, [it could very well be the opposite](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions?lq=1#comment712145_219932 "Summing up, I would downvote about 101-118 of 218 answers I reviewed per above research"))

Comment: It's not the only criteria, @gnat. It is the most significant, since by the time you filter it down to folks *doing* something on the destination the numbers are very small. FWIW, I think I've pointed out before that what you actually *want* (regardless of what you state) is the complete removal of hot questions from the network. That's a valid position to take, but I tend to think you're biased by your love for problematic topics when considering the implications of this.

Comment: idea to drop the list is [your](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190106/dealing-with-find-out-whos-going-to-buy-the-croissants/190413#comment590116_190413), [not mine](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=10591104#10591104), we already been through this before, is there a need to repeat what has been discussed? If you want removing it so badly, why don't you just put feature request at MSO and see how it will fly

Comment: Whether you want to admit it or not, @gnat, that's what you're arguing for: you want to replace it with *something else*, but can't seem to muster the nerve to just say that. And I think I know why: the hot lists are [a convenient boogieman](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions/220099#220099) for deeper quality issues. I don't deny the appeal of blaming the barbarians, but [it was wrong three years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl/73396#73396) and it's just as wrong now.

Comment: @Shog9 I would possibly buy that if only I could see; if I could see that trouble brought by _genuinely_ hot questions correlates with site quality issues, I'd probably join your crusade. But the way how things work now doesn't allow for that - hot questions are _[fake](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164078/165773)_ way too much and way too often to make any meaningful conclusions based on them. Maybe that's why you're alone in your quest for HQ removal, people just suspect that you're throwing out the baby with the bathwater

Comment: Well, [what's the baby](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions) here, @gnat?

Comment: [clear the muddy waters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216260/165773) first, then let's check if there's baby left - as of now, it's impossible to see if there's anything in there. As I wrote, if I find that _genuinely_ hot questions correlate to site quality issues, I am going to join your crusade for their removal.

Comment: showing random questions is stupid. just now, I saw two interesting questions, clicked one, and the other is gone :(

Comment: *it may end up having horrible side-effects that result in it being tied up in a sack with a brick, thrown off a bridge and never spoken of again.*  -  Ohh no I promise every time you try something new we will point back to this and say remember the Hot Question List debacle...

Comment: I have plenty of extra bricks and sacks, @Chad!

Comment: I like this change. Please keep it!

Comment: This post is referred to quite widely across this meta. Could you add a quick update to the answer stating whether this has been definitively enabled across the board?

Comment: We want to understand how current algorithm works to provide feed-back on [Revisiting HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha?cb=1). Can you shed some light?