# The new hot questions algorithm sometimes recurses

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hot-questions

The hot questions algorithm [was changed recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218248/228098). I like the effects, since I see lots of new interesting stuff every day rather than waiting <s>6-8 weeks</s> varying amounts of time for the list to update.

However, the new algorithm also has the interesting side effect of recursing the same question:

[image: "Did you like this question? You might also be interested in reading it from this link over here!]

Of course, this is a <s>world-shattering workflow-breaking unicorn-hating waffle-despising ERROR</s> tremendously minor matter. But, if the SE devs have opportunity during their amazingly large amounts of free time, it might be nice to add a check for the current page before populating the hot questions list.

Comment: Well it is *still* a hot question even if you're on the question

Comment: @AlienArrays: I'm trying to follow that and failing. (No coffee today.) Are you quite sure you didn't mean "duplication"?

Comment: @AlienArrays I suppose you could say that you can follow a link to the question again and again. But really by that definition the main page recurses too. To be truly recersive I would expect it to autoload the page over and over by redirecting to itself

Comment: Not a new behavior and not a bug. When visiting hot qustion from the list, it will still appear in the list.

Comment: I noticed that even reloading the page will give different list of hot questions

Comment: @BЈовић That is correct - see [What changed in the Hot Questions sidebar algorithm?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218247/what-changed-in-the-hot-questions-sidebar-algorithm/218248#218248)

Answer (score 7):

This is not a bug. This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). A question should still show up as hot if you're on that page. It would be too much effort for too little reward to fix this. Plus, you're not a  mindless webcrawler (hopefully) that just follows all the links on the pages. Even if you were a webcrawler, you'd probably avoid links going to your current location.

Comment: Any webcrawler that blindly went to all links on a page would get trapped by any question as well because the title links back to itself (which is useful when on a URL to an answer/comment)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Jonathan. The Hot Network Questions sidebar never provides a full snapshot of the questions that are currently on the list, but only a subset. As such, the absence of any given question from the sidebar does **not** imply that the question is no longer "hot".

Behaviour like this adds no value and it simply looks buggy:

> [image]

The only way to claim "this is not a bug" with a straight face is to seriously believe that the desired behaviour was a buggy-looking webpage.

Beyond that, scrblnrd3's "too much effort" argument is ridiculous. If this takes more than one line of code to fix, I'll eat my hat.