# Prevent showing current question in HNQ sidebar

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hot-questions

Sometimes when visiting a Hot Network Question question, that very same question will sometimes appear in the HNQ sidebar. Example here:

[image]

Silly sidebar, I've already seen that question--I'm there right now!

Can we add a feature to remove the currently viewed question from the possible list of HNQ questions that populate the sidebar?

This is not a duplicate of [The new hot questions algorithm sometimes recurses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219875/the-new-hot-questions-algorithm-sometimes-recurses), as that is a bug report that was marked as by design. On the other hand, this is a feature request asking that the design be changed.

Comment: That looks like a nice task for an userscript.

Comment: Ahh I figured it'd be a dupe but couldn't find it when I was searching. Thanks for the catch, @animuson!

Comment: @animuson This is not a duplicate. This was tagged as a feature request, and hence is a request to change the design, not a duplicate of a bug report that was marked as by design.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog The whole "it's by-design let's make a feature request to change it" thing is kind of ridiculous. All another question here would do is repeat the same things said there, and result in us not changing it. I could just as easily just change the tags on the other question to feature-request and status-declined, problem solved.

Comment: @animuson What if someone brought up new arguments in favor of changing it?

Comment: Is it that annoying? If one question is in the HNQ then it's there. Sometimes you can be on a page and be blissfully unaware that the post is "hot".