# What does"Questions with most views, answers and votes" mean?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

What does"Questions with most views, answers and votes" mean? I just don't get it, how does SE arrange questions with hotness? It does not seem to arrange questions with the most views or votes.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/221351

Comment: see also: [What changed in the Hot Questions sidebar algorithm?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218247/what-changed-in-the-hot-questions-sidebar-algorithm)