# "Hot Network Questions" randomizes too much when navigation in browser history

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, back-button

I really love the "Hot Network Questions" (**HNQ**) as I love to look at what other communities do; in german I would say "Ich liebe es, über den Tellerrand zu schauen" (Love looking beyond my own's backyard?)

However: Most of the time, I discover hot questions *while* loading another site (i.e. when I am forced to look around), and this imposes problems and makes the feature almost unusable for me. This is my typical workflow for HNQ-usage:

- Grasp topic *"How to foo the bar"*
- Done or Clicking some link leading me to further details about *Frob*
- This is the moment I have a quick glance on the **HNQ**

  - I see some interesting *"What's a John?"* from a foreign field *Doe D'Oh*
  - Whoosh, the page load completes and I think "Oh noes, but I was interested in *"What's a John?"*
  - `go-back-one-page`
  - "Oh no, it's gone."
  - "Ah I know, search for the topic using the search-box"
  - *Argh, this ain't work. I don't find it. Let's hope it pops up again*

My proposal now is (sorry if I miss the proper terminology):

**Make the HNQ permament w.r.t. the history, i.e. when you click `go-back/forward`, it should show the same questions from when you initially loaded this entry in the history**

---

**edit:** A dupe was proposed. However, it talks about page-reload. I think randomization is okay upon reload and loading a new instance; changing contents is what we reload for. I really look for staticness w.r.t. to a single "page-instance", when navigating forward and backward again.

Comment: <strike>Duplicates welcome. I missed to look for "Randomness".</strike>  edit: However, I have no problem with randomizing on page-reload; that's what a page-reload is for. But navigation forward and backward shouldn't change the contents, imho.

Comment: Also related: [What changed in the Hot Questions sidebar algorithm?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218247)

Comment: @BillyMailman: Yeah, that seems to fit. Now I think I have another feature proposal ...

Comment: The first "dupe" is not a dupe at all. Very poor choice to include that link here, as I nearly requested a fix for this yet again.