# How do hot questions on a single site contribute to hot network questions sidebar?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Every site has a ["hot questions" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot). These questions "sometimes" show up in the hot network questions sidebar based on a [complex algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218248/165773).

That sidebar is engineered to show hot questions across sites but in a highly dynamic way that even changes on page refreshes (ie isn't designed to be "stable" and is intentionally designed to be somewhat "unstable").

Is there a way to find out what hot questions on a single site are being displayed in the [network-wide hot questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) list?

My interest is finding hot questions on my favorite sites that make the network hot questions list, even momentarily. It seems some of my favorite sites do not have high voting and it is a somewhat uncommon and noteworthy event that they make the network hot questions list.

It's also a useful way to know when there may be a lot of "outside" interest in a particular question due to cross-site dropping in. Another interesting idea/closely related feature would be to have some kind of chat room question feed mechanism that could post only questions that made the network hot questions list on a single site of interest.

Related: [What is the Goal of "Hot Network Questions"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions)

Comment: For the chat room feed, see [How can I add Hot Network Questions (HNQ) to a chat room feed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313353/how-can-i-add-hot-network-questions-hnq-to-a-chat-room-feed)