# How can I add Hot Network Questions (HNQ) to a chat room feed?

Tags: support, chat, hot-questions, feed

I would like to MYOH (Make Your Own HNQ) by posting hot network questions (HNQ) as a chat feed to a chat room. This offers the following benefits:

- Filter out HNQ from specific sites, or equivalently, add HNQ only from specific sites
- Add HNQ to a "read later" list

There doesn't seem to be any site-specific feed for HNQ, nor any way to distinguish HNQ from "ordinary" questions (other than the roundabout ways of guessing from number of views or going to archive.org, etc.).

How would I configure the chat feed to achieve this?

Comment: You mean [this feed](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions)? That's the only HNQ feed that exists. The list is global across the entire network - there aren't separate lists for each site. Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a way to filter out certain sites from HNQ. Seems that there's no way of doing it directly in the HNQ list, so I was hoping for an MYOH solution as described above.

Comment: Related: [Accessing the Hot Network Questions via the API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275704/accessing-the-hot-network-questions-via-the-api)

Answer (score 24):

There is no such standard functionality on the site. You would need a server side implementation that responds to the Feeds bots requests and produce an RSS feed from the Hot Network Questions list.

I've created an app in Glitch [here](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/) (and find the implementation [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lackadaisical-appeal))

The Glitch app offers a route `/hnq/:site`. This route returns an XML RSS Feed. The feed can then be read by the Stack Exchange Feeds bot. The bot will then post new items in the chatroom.

The `:site` parameter can be

- a single domain name of a site
- an exact domain name match of a site, indicated by a = as prefix
- a list of domains to include, indicated by a + as prefix
- a list of domains to exclude, indicated by a - as prefix
- a combination of domains to match, include and exclude

Examples of each option are

- [`/hnq/askubuntu.com`](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/askubuntu.com)
- [`/hnq/askubuntu+ell+aviation`](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/askubuntu+ell+aviation) (notice that the first + can be omitted)
- [`/hnq/=cs.stackexchange.com`](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/=cs.stackexchange.com) (exactly cs.stackexchange.com)
- [`/hnq/-stackexchange.com`](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/-stackexchange.com) (no sites that have *stackexchange.com* in their name)
- [`/hnq/+overflow-stackoverflow.com`](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/+overflow-stackoverflow.com) (the overflow sites, not stackoverflow)
- [`/hnq/-`](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/-) (exclusion with empty argument, showing *all* sites instead)

Here is an image showing how you can configure a feed in your room:

[image: configure feed in a chatroom]

And you can see the result of the RSS items being posted [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43569499#43569499).

Additionally  there are RSS feeds for [migrated questions](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/migrations), basically offering an implementation for [Make migrated questions eligible for First Posts review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345238)

The app also offers an [interactive Chart](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/chart) to see all the hot questions, their score and answers plotted  over time.

[image: Bubble plot of 100 questions over time and their score]