# How to list all the Hot Network Questions on a specific site?

Tags: support, hot-questions

Suppose I wanted to view all the Hot Network Questions on a specific site (say, Stack Overflow). Is there a straightforward way to do so?

Also, is it possible to list all the HNQ across the whole network (since the sidebar only shows some of them)?

Comment: You can have them as RSS feed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314073/158100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your best bet is going to https://stackexchange.com/, which lists all the current Hot Network Questions, and spot the ones from the site you're interested in.

Even if it's not 100% straightforward, as the HNQ system was recently reworked so that at most 5 questions come from the same site, you shouldn't be loosing too much time browsing the 4 pages of question titles - it's "only" 100 questions. (Provided you don't get distracted by the other questions!)

Comment: Oh yeah, I read about the "five questions at most" rule but forgot about it. I guess your suggestion isn't a bad idea in this case.

Comment: You can view 50 at a time, so it's only two pages.

Answer (score 4):

Another option, especially useful if you need to [parse the Hot Network Questions list with code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315017/295232), is to use the following undocumented API: https://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-for-mobile (as its name implies, it's used by the Stack Exchange mobile apps). It lists all 100 questions, as opposed to the stackexchange.com homepage which has two (or more) pages.

[image]