# Make migrated questions eligible for First Posts review

Tags: feature-request, review, migration

It looks like migrated posts don't end up in the First Posts review queue, even if they would qualify otherwise. [Here](https://stackapps.com/q/8592/34061) is an example, the [timeline](https://stackapps.com/posts/8592/timeline) shows there's no completed First Posts review and that [review queue](https://stackapps.com/review) is empty as well.

I don't see why migrated posts should be treated differently than non-migrated posts; in fact, one could argue that migrated posts might actually benefit *more* from review than non-migrated posts: a prime example being adding tags which didn't exist on the original site. Also, sometimes poor quality posts get migrated, making a review even more desirable.

Comment: Completely agree. Never really thought about this but indeed - migrated questions should be looked even more, since migration doesn't ensure the question is *completely* OK for the new stack. Yes, steps are taken to not just migrate crap but even if the question is decent, it might need to be improved for the other stack.

Comment: Can we take this one step further and put *all* migrated questions in a review queue?

Comment: @Mast sure: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149825/295232

Answer (score 6):

Until this is implemented I've added the Migrated Questions RSS feeds to the [SE HNQ Feed App](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/).

This is how it works:

- Create or grab the live feed from [/migrations](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/migrations).
- Add the RSS feed to an SE chatroom, see for example the [SO Migrations](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/68414/socvr-testing-facility?tab=feeds) feed in the SOCVR Test room.
- Wait for the feed to have a question.
- Success!

Alternatively you can visit the [tracked migrated posts](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/migrations/posts) to find the migrated questions across the network.

There also is a [status page](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/migrations/status) that shows when the last check for migrated questions was done for a specific site.

#### How does this work?

The app makes Stack Exchange API calls on a schedule to [/search/advanced](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) with the migrated parameter set to true for every site that has a live migration feed requested. It stores the site and question in a database so it can serve the RSS feed at any moment without burning API requests. It is basically one big caching extravaganza.

#### Fair use

The API request limit is 10,000 calls per day. This is enough to make a call every 20 seconds. All sites are visited in a round-robin manner. If you are curating a site that hardly ever sees a migration, it is preferred you **DO NOT** request a live feed for your site. This guarantees the app can serve more sites more frequently which is beneficial for the sites that are very frequently on the receiving end of migrations.