# Reasoning behind changing the main portal's homepage and focus

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, hot-questions

https://stackexchange.com/ went through a major change somewhere between June 11<sup>th</sup> and June 12<sup>th</sup> according to the Wayback Machine.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20140611173246/https://stackexchange.com/) is how it looked like before, with focus on the sites/communities and many links from the homepage itself. After the change, the homepage is showing only the list of Hot Network Questions, sorted by hotness points (can be seen as tooltip) and for anonymous visitors (i.e. those not logged in) also showing a nice "Stack Exchange Q&A communities are different. Here's how" banner on top.

So the focus changed drastically from *sites* to *questions*, and all links removed, making it cleaner.

I am not challenging the change, just curious to know the reasoning behind it, what motivated such a change, and whether it's successful or not e.g. more incoming traffic from the portal to sites needing traffic?

Worth to mention, this new design is very similar to the first design of the portal (since Stack Exchange 2.0 was declared) as can be seen [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100811003728/http://www.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't like the new design, by the way. Older was better.

Comment: I diligently scrolled the Tour to the bottom, hoping for an Informed badge on *Main Stack Exchange* site. Alas... But I am very happy to see the randomly rotating site banners gone. Those were getting on my nerves.

Comment: @nicael my initial impression too but after a while I did like it. Sometimes it needs time to get used to a change.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier lol, secret badge could be cool! :)

Comment: I'm barely aware of that landing page, can't remember any recent visits. Seeing both for essentially the first time, the current version is immediately more pleasing - it flows a lot better.

Comment: wonder how old is that new design? _'I really like the new Stack Exchange home page, where certain questions from the Stack Exchange Network are presented, along with a hotness rating that is described as "arbitrary" in its tooltip...'_ ([asked Aug 12 '10](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/165773):)

Comment: @gnat I believe he's referring to the Hot Questions page that was linked from the homepage, the design was changed less than a month ago as proved by the Wayback Machine.

Comment: @gnat [It changed on/around June 12th](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16043167#16043167).

Comment: @ShadowWizard nope, if you check the question, there's linkified text referring same URL as your: "[new Stack Exchange home page](http://stackexchange.com)"

Comment: @gnat true, I've edited the question to add this interesting part. No exactly same design but very similar indeed.

Comment: yes, and that old "hot questions based" design has been there up until [Feb '12](https://web.archive.org/web/20120328032437/http://stackexchange.com/), and it changed to "sites list based" in [Mar '12](https://web.archive.org/web/20120328032437/http://stackexchange.com/) (side note consider adding screen shots to wayback machine links, as some corporate firewalls block it)

Comment: @gnat nice detective work! All the more reason to get some official response. I'm afraid screenshots would get messy but will think again about it. :)

Comment: (just show screen shots as links, not images) My further "private investigation" included studying of SE blog in Feb-Mar '12, I didn't found anything about homepage there. But... there's concern about [When a Site Grows Quiet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/). And, incidentally or not, at about this time hot questions formula began breaking quite noticeably ([sticky questions list revisions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/99077/revisions?page=2) began piling in fall '12 with examples that went especially blatantly wrong)...

Comment: ...and, incidentally or not, but in Feb this year team began [testing of "shuffling" hot questions in sidebar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218248/165773), and per my observations they appear to be satisfied with how things go recently (I think they're wrong, but it will take time for them to find out - as an example Mad Scientist has been pushing to solve issue of sticky questions for 2,5 years)

Comment: (I hate to sound like a broken record _hot-questions-hot-questions-hot..._ but the more I learn about this homepage thing, the more it feels "tightly coupled")

Comment: @gnat well, doesn't look like we're going to get any official response. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard it's weekend, SE guys likely will take a look at this question later. Besides, we can keep the question active with bounties (and I for one plan to give it at least 3 bounties before giving up:)

Comment: update: [Podcast #60 (07-16-14)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/07/podcast-60-are-we-that-predictable/) refers this change: "We redesigned [the Stack Exchange homepage](http://stackexchange.com/)… again. (The pendulum swings.)" Have to admit I was too lazy to listen, maybe there are more details about the change there

Comment: @gnat true, wish a team member will come here to summarize this officially.

Comment: there you go - I just [added a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/235101/revisions) :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, we only respond when bounties are on the line! (Sorry for the delay - I actually just hadn't seen it on the first pass, but spotted it on the home page today when I had a few to respond...)

Comment: @Jaydles yup, nothing like the shine of fresh repz to draw attention. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**

**If we assume most visitors to SE.com are trying to find out what we're about, the page should focus on *showing* them content that may convey what we do, not *telling them* why our content is better.**

We also wanted it to be potentially useful to existing users who are interested in browsing other sites on the network.  (A few of us here read it every morning to find interesting questions or learn something.)

**More Detailed Color**

The old home page had a feel that seemed less like a good indication of what (we think) makes our communities special, and more like everything a reporter or someone curious about the *company* might want to know.

We asked two questions - who do we want to talk to, and what do want to convey?

- **We want to talk to users or potential users, not reporters, investors, etc.**
- **We want to focus on *showing* them the kind of content they might find on our sites, with as short a summary as possible of what makes that content better.**

The old homepage didn't achieve this as well as we'd hoped for a coupla reasons:

- **It showed a total of just six questions,** which meant that it was *very* unlikely that someone browsing would see one that was a topic they knew (which could therefore help convey the kind of hopefully high-quality content that would interest them.)
- **It focused too much on stats, network growth, and *descriptions* of question quality**. But it's a lot harder to *tell* someone your quality is better than other Q&A than it is to *show* them.
- **A lot of space was highlighting 3 sites.** Even if they *happened* to be ones you cared about (unlikely), there's still not much to make you see what may be better here than on other sites on that topic.
- **Almost a third of the page highlighted site blogs and contact info.** Blogs on most sites are updated pretty rarely, and the focus on contact info might help a reporter, but not a potential user checking us out.

So, for the new one:

- **We focus on content,** which we think best conveys what our sites are about.
- **We also try to get across what *makes that content happen*** in the areas not devoted to the content itself.  Specifically:

  1. The Big Three in the box on top: Expert Communities, Ranked Answers, and Earned Trust
  2. One featured community, mostly just to convey the idea of separate communities for each topic in a tangible way
  3. Some network users to convey the notion that real, live human people (like you!) create all the awesome content here.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. One thing though: it still feels weird to write "Stack Exchange community" instead of "Stack Exchange site". Don't you think it makes one think "community? hey, so it must be a social forum!". No?

Comment: <nitpick>"what makes that content _better_..." - word _better_ here looks somewhat... not 100% accurate, taking into account that what you show (hot questions) is intended to focus on [entertaining](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220099/165773) / [interesting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222730/165773) stuff, not on high quality one</nitpick> (for the sake of completeness, same word looks perfectly okay when used in another context - "_better_ than other Q&A" - this is so true)