# Is it acceptable to cross-post questions to site *metas*?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, cross-posting

I recently posted [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346236/would-it-be-appropriate-to-draw-attention-to-ask-patents-software-prior-art-requ) on MSO when pursuing options for [Directing Prior Art Searches from Ask Patents](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293153/directing-prior-art-searches-from-ask-patents).

After reviewing the newly added example prior art request, I'd essentially like to post the exact same discussion on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and possibly elsewhere.

- In general, is cross-posting on site metas acceptable?
- Does this specific case differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the question.

If you're asking e.g. a support question, such as "How do I use X feature?" then cross-posting isn't really a good idea. Either ask here (assuming it's applicable to more than one site; but if you're considering cross-posting then I guess it is) or on a specific site's meta. But pick one; don't do both... the same logic applies to cross-posting regular Q&As. Of course, different communities have different interpretations and usage of rules and features, so it's probably OK if you're asking in the vein of "How do I use X feature; and how does it's use differ here as opposed to site Y".

If you're asking for direct input from a specific community about something which you want to do on that specific site (as your question is)... then yes, of course post on the different metas... seems like a no brainer to me.