# Where to ask about existence of prior art in floating point algorithm field

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about prior art, not specifically about patents, but rather out of curiosity, because I'd like to learn more on the subject.

Since my question is technical, and that I know that some good specialists are hanging on SO, I would be tempted to ask there, even if the question is not specifically about programming, but rather meta-SO.

In a few words, there are techniques to reduce the significand of a floating point number in the range [1.0,2.0) or in [0.5,1.0), but it is also possible to reduce it in [2/3,4/3], which can be an advantage for functions like log. I named that *balancedSignificand* here [https://smallissimo.blogspot.com/2021/03/autopsy-of-accuracy-problem-of-log2-in.html](https://smallissimo.blogspot.com/2021/03/autopsy-of-accuracy-problem-of-log2-in.html?showComment=1614902211911#c1042884996937891189). I want to know if the technique is already known (I'm pretty sure it is), named, and where to discover more... If not, is it found useful?

I have read
[Directing Prior Art Searches from Ask Patents](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293153) but I don't even know which chat room the accepted answer is about, and I'm not focused on patents specifically.

I have also read the excellent [Where do I ask where to ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168103) which makes me hope that this question is not completely disqualified, since instantiating the meta-meta level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: I’d suggest https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case, prior art of mathematics and potentially patents, you would probably be able to ask about this on our "[History of Mathematics and Science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" site. Their chat room, "[On the way to Damascus](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117320/on-the-way-to-damascus)" has minimal but recent activity; there or their meta might be a good place to start.

- Your question must be about **the history**, though it can be recent, see: "[What exactly is History?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263/10320)" and "[How many years to be considered as history?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/189/10320)", maybe even "[Are questions of the type 'Did person X do action Y' on topic?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/146/10320)", and probably "[Is history of Computer science on topic?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/10320)".
- The closest to **yes** seems to come from the answer to: "[Are history of engineering/invention questions on topic?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30/10320)", with the caveat: "... these [questions] clearly demonstrate and focus on an application of scientific and/or mathematical principles for these inventions to work.".
- While not necessarily related to patents the Help file's example points to: "[Who discovered smooth non-analytic functions of a real variable?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/727/10320)", which asks about the discover (assignee) rather than about the potential [assignee](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s301.html) of any subsequent patents.
- They have [**13** questions](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/search?q=patent+is%3Aquestion) mentioning patents and [**54** "prior"- based](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22prior%22+is%3Aquestion) questions, at least some relevant.
- The [HSM Meta](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) only has **128** questions, and I don't see a duplicate of what you ask here, so it's certainly possible to ask there if it's on-topic; maybe even obtaining some helpful advice in a comment.