# Is it possible for me to exclude certain sites from my view of Hot Network Questions?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

There are some SE sites I am simply not at all interested in, and never will be.

Is it possible for me to filter certain sites from showing up in the Hot Network Questions list, and if not, can this be considered?  Perhaps a setting in the profile?

Also, once I view a certain Hot Question - Can it be prevented from showing up in the future days?

Comment: As far I know, the HNQ question toolbar tracks your click probability to the induvidual sites, and recalibrates the probability of the question appearance to follow it. Somewhere I've read here on the meta, that the SE allows for you, to see what probabilities is it thinking currently from you, and on which reason.

Comment: @peterh [citation needed] ? As far as I know, it's just random.

Comment: @Catija Only my remembers, this is why the "as far I know" and this is why I wrote this in comment. If you really want, I can search for that.

Comment: [The SOX user-script](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) supports excluding certain sites from HNQ.

Comment: @peterh They use an algorithm to shuffle the links but it's not based on the user, only based on how high up the links are in the HNQ list. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218248/284336 It's called a [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: @Catija I am sure, once I've seen a downloadable JSON export. It was years before. It seems, I am the only one remembering it. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Many adblocker supports induvidual css deny lists. This:

```
div[title="Role-playing Games Stack Exchange"],
div[title="Role-playing Games Stack Exchange"] + a {
  display: none;
}
```

would eliminate the RPG SE from the HNQ toolbar (the selection of the RPG SE happened by that it was on the top on my HNQ and doesn't have secondary meaning).

Comment: I don't want to use external tools to modify the output of SE. I want a setting so i can run it natively... I use Stack sites at work, other PCs which might not have the same extensions etc

Comment: @GWR Well.. you are right. Maybe you could put the whole HNQ div into an adblocker.

Comment: The second point is not remotely close. Personalized prediction data does exist but it has absolutely nothing to do with HNQ. The HNQ list is just a list of questions generated for the entire network.

Comment: peterh - I'd suggest if you remove the incorrect point 2, you may get upvotes for your remaining point

Comment: @RoryAlsop I think it is better if I delete this post, because so it seems that I accuse the SE. But I am sure, what I can remember. But I can't dig out this old post.

Comment: no - your post is good now. Have my upvote :-)

Comment: @animuson Ok. I removed the problematic part. But years ago I myself downloaded some such data from the SE, it was a JSON file and it contained maybe probabilities. I did it as I read it somewhere on the sites, probably in an SE insider post. Maybe it wasn't from the HNQ queue, but it was a JSON from what the SE thinks from my some preferences. For that, I remember clearly, but I can't find any trace of it now.

Comment: @animuson Sorry I've remembered! I've talked about the [Personalized Prediction Data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/prediction-data) (downloadable by everybody from its own profile).