# What's the standard way to promote questions to Twitter?

Tags: support, twitter

Suppose I see a post on say Electronics SE which I think should be tweeted on Electronics SE Twitter account.

So far I was flagging such questions for moderator attention commenting that the question would be great for tweeting. I'm not sure it's the best way.

What's the conventional way I should follow for this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, questions for the Twitter bot accounts are pre-selected. Mods have no control over what questions are pushed to the bots other than minor adjustments ([The Twitter bot should not Tweet posts that have flags on them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124994/the-twitter-bot-should-not-tweet-posts-that-have-flags-on-them))

There used to be a form that could be used by moderators to promote questions to the bot by asking SE Inc., but I don't think it works again. The standard way would be to use your personal account to tweet posts.

> Ultimately, we want to promote YOU, not the site itself. We want to be awesome by association with you. Asking you to subsume your entire Twitter identity into a faceless "Stack*" Twitter account does not strike me as the right way to accomplish this goal. - Jeff Atwood <sup>[[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92235/would-allowing-moderators-to-update-their-stack-exchange-sites-twitter-account)]</sup>

Comment: IIRC, downvotes at all invalidate the question from being tweeted.