# Tweeting a question posted less than an hour ago with a single upvote

Tags: discussion, question-quality, twitter

Related: [Avoid tweeting bad questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115722/165773)

> ...Shouldn't questions be given enough time to be vetted by the community before they're shouted to the twitter universe?

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/269484/revisions) has been tweeted less than an hour after it was posted. As far as I can tell, at this moment it had a single upvote, no comments and no answers. Quoting related question referred above, "maybe it's time to be a little more selective?"

---

Incidentally, it turned out a fairly straightforward off-topic - [resource recommendation](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487) / [where-to-start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260) request. Which makes one wonder if it is expected for close voters and flaggers to monitor every new question 24x7 [just to prevent this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115899/165773) from happening? As far as I know, [this is not how system is expected to work](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14524409#14524409):

> It's a frickin' volunteer position - you do it when you have the time to do it.

See also: [Should we be concerned that @StackProgrammer tweets refer to closed/deleted questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/should-we-be-concerned-that-stackprogrammer-tweets-refer-to-closed-deleted-ques)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, someone *was* monitoring it... And they upvoted it!

That said, I tend to agree that a single upvote is a bit of a low bar for promotion, and this is hardly the only site where we've seen problems as a result of this. So I've raised the threshold score to 3 for this particular category.