# Why is StackChess' account blocked on Twitter?

Tags: discussion, twitter

I just noticed a strange thing: the account that tweets HNQ on Chess.SE ([StackChess](https://twitter.com/StackChess)) has been suspended. This must have happened between [Jan 29](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/28225) and [Jan 30](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/28237)

Yet, there are still sites ([Workplace](https://twitter.com/StackWorkplace), [Academia](https://twitter.com/StackAcademia)) that haven't got the respective Twitter accounts blocked.

How many SE Twitter accounts have been suspended so far and do we know why?

Comment: I think they got classed as unauthorized bots, and I remember that that's why SE stopped making Twitter accounts for new sites.

Comment: Sonic is right. Twitter suspends them because they are bots making automated tweets, but only Twitter could say why it suspends some of the bots and not others.

Comment: @animuson They'll never tell you, else they'll have to kill your bot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that Twitter suddenly and randomly started blocking those accounts because they were bots posting automated tweets and that resulted in SE [not creating new Twitter accounts for new sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548) since 2015. It's still not known why Twitter has deleted [only some of the accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358449/why-is-stackchess-account-blocked-on-twitter/358514#comment1197036_358449).