# What to do with questions trying to replicate discussion forums on SO?

Tags: discussion, flags, old-questions

So I was just minding my own business, doing searches and flagging answers that aren't so they could be removed by people with more rep than me when I came across these two questions:

[C# HttpWebResponse Comet problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742631/c-httpwebresponse-comet-problem/4644184#4644184)

[concatenate several fields into one with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696/concatenate-several-fields-into-one-with-sql/37738#37738).

and I was at a loss.

In the first one a user does the old question-in-an-answer trick and then goes on to answer his own question in a subsequent answer. What a mess, I thought. But then I saw number two... which is clearly an attempt to pull off a webforum-esque conversation on Stackoverflow: OP asks question, gets answer, accepts answers, asks question in new answer, gets answers to that from guy who wrote accepted answer in yet another answer etc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag non-answers as non-answers and moderators can make them comments.

For actual answers that then pose follow-up questions, post a comment guiding them to create a new question for that question.

Comment: what if the answers with follow-up questions are old?

Comment: Doesn't change anything, they'll still get notified if you post a comment.  As long as the new answer to the old question is still valuable, no need to do anything other than say "hey instead of posting this follow-up question in your answer here, you should probably post a completely new question"

Answer (score 2):

Your second link was from *Ought Eight*, back when there were no comments.  Always remember that older questions are rife with users doing things that aren't accepted anymore.

If you see an older question with comment-answers, off topic questions, etc etc instead of flagging, just edit and stick this at the top:

> This question exists because it has
>   historical significance, but it is not
>   considered a good, on-topic question
>   for this site, so please do not use it
>   as evidence that you can ask similar
>   questions here.
>
> More info: https://stackoverflow.com/faq

(I forget who I stole this from, my bad)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80272/should-old-off-topic-posts-be-migrated-and-under-what-criteria/80536#80536

Comment: @random: My thievery, exposed.

Comment: Will do. Just define 'older'. :)

Comment: @dandan78: A good rule of thumb is questions from July 2009 or earlier (within the first year).  I usually go for anything from 09, but some might have an issue with that.