# Why are people closing "What <x> is best?" questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

What JavaScript framework is best? Can anyone recommend books that are best? Etc...

Obviously these questions involve a lot of opinion but well-informed opinions from a large body of developers are still valuable.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394182/best-reference-book-for-extjs-4
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107015/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs-dhtmlx-vs-ext-js-sencha

Comment: Why am I getting bazooka-voted-down for asking a simple question?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying

Comment: Additionally, note that downvotes are a bit different on Meta than they are on the main site. The [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) contains more details.

Answer (score 9):

> Obviously these questions involve a lot of opinion but well-informed opinions from a large body of developers are still valuable.

Neither question has that though. They're broad, ill-defined, and duplicate topics already on the site - badly. Neither one has more than a single answer, and neither answer looks exceptionally well-informed - the ExtJS answer explicitly states that the question is poor!

I really can't imagine why you are shocked to see them closed, but if you think there's value in the topics you would do well to edit them into shape before asking for them to be re-opened.

Comment: They aren't my questions. I just don't see anything in the FAQs that indicates these types of comparison Qs should be crushed.

Comment: @Erik: One of them isn't a comparison question; he's just asking for  a book. The other... [Read this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: The guy wants a book recommendation. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Erik: after taking another look at that question, I think the problems with it were probably superficial - while I question the need for such a question (the official Ext JS website provides quite a lot of documentation...) I've edited to correct the style and re-opened. Like it or not, appearance *does* matter: if you see a question closed that you feel should not have been, editing it for clarity is your best first option when it comes to getting that overturned.

Answer (score 3):

They are getting closed because they are rather subjective, as what the best framework is depends from what you need it for.
The other problem I see with those questions is that, when a new framework comes out, a new answer should be added; this means that the question would be interesting for the future users if it is kept updated.

Answer (score 3):

Those get closed because as per the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), they don't belong on the site.

`Closing` just means that no new answers can be posted, the question is still on the site for all to see and read.  Where people go over the line is when they start `deleting` those questions, which shouldn't happen for programming related ones, though they might get migrated to other sites if relevant.

Questions [that are useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete/102993#102993) but don't have the potential for more really useful answers to be added, should be `locked`.

For questions that have potential for more useful answers, they can also be `protected` which only disallows drive-by posts by those little rep.

Comment: "Where people go over the line is when they start deleting those questions" -- that's not how it's supposed to work at all. Closing is supposed to be the precursor to deletion; there are no questions that should be closed but not deleted other than really old questions that we leave out of pity and exact duplicates that we leave for search purposes

Comment: @michael, __NO__, that's not the purpose of deletion, though it's abused that way.  See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51097/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2010) by Jeff, and all the related links for the conversation that we had on this.  Closing in NOT an supposed to be an automatic precursor for deletion, it has it's own purpose.

Comment: If the questions were still bad enough to be closed, they should then be deleted. Jeff is talking about merging the answers into a better question if one exists; that doesn't mean the bad question should then be left around. From the blog: ["When you vote to close a question, you are really voting for that question to be eventually deleted."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/adventures-in-delclusionism/)

Comment: @Lance: you mean the post that leads off with, **"closed questions which are not useful in either content or as a search term variety duplicate, absolutely should be deleted."** all in bold just like that? And then goes on to talk about the exceptions where *merging* is preferable? Because *that* post doesn't support your argument at all...

Comment: @Michael, questions don't always get closed because they're `bad`.  __Bad__ questions should be deleted.  There are plenty of questions that should be closed, but aren't bad.  Here's a great reason from Jeff, [questions with good answers should not be deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50069/why-are-we-deleting-instead-of-merging/50106#50106).

Comment: @shog9, I remember all the conversation well on the topic.  See the link I just posted in the last comment.  The quote is "I wish people wouldn't delete questions with good answers. You're destroying the useful contributions of your peers!"

Comment: @Lance: the one that contains huge bold header-text stating, **"Flag these for moderator attention instead and suggest a merge!"**? You seem to be digging up arguments against deleting duplicates, which are *completely valid and extremely important exceptions* to the rule Mrozek cites, but... also completely irrelevant for the discussion at hand.

Comment: @shog9, to reference your 'non-support' argument, my argument is that `useful` posts shouldn't be deleted, even if they're closed.  And yes as we all know, `useful` posts get closed all the time.  The quote from Jeff on that one, "Questions which contain useful content contributed by your peers should generally be merged, not deleted."

Comment: @Shog9, I have no idea why you think they're irrelevant.  The relevant point is that questions can be closed without thought of deletion.  They are two separate (though functionally related) processes.

Comment: The relevant point is that if you see a useful question closed *and you don't think it should be deleted*, then you need to **vote to re-open it**. Not sit around complacently because you think the question is "finished" and closing simply prevents other, lesser, answers from being posted... [Closing == CALL TO ACTION](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete) - whether that is editing, re-opening, merging, or deletion...

Comment: @Shog9, NO, that's my point.  I should be able to let questions be closed, without fear of them being deleted.  That's actually why I vote to close fewer questions now, since so many people want to delete the `useful` content that was requested not to be deleted.  It has ruined the functionality of closure.  Closing is not always a call to action, it's also an end result, a place questions with `useful` information can go that we want to preserve, but also need to stop the answer flow.

Comment: @Shog9, I've posted an [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete/102993#102993) on the post you linked to.  It looks like Michael has changed his mind since his answer there.

Comment: @Lance: you're arguing for a feature that has *never* existed: closing as a farm up-state where old questions go to live out their lives in peace... That's a myth, a story misguided folk tell to children who've become too attached to beloved but rabid pets. The purpose of closing is to provide a limbo where the question and/or answers can be improved, debated, etc. prior to outright deletion - the number of cases where we want [some "mark of Cain" for questions is minuscule](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80536), and better handled by *locking* in any case.

Comment: @Shog9, I'm not averse to `locking`, though it's hard to imagine a question I'd `lock` and not `close`.  In fact, I'd say most of the `closed` questions that shouldn't be `deleted` should be `locked` (maybe all, but that would take a lot of research to determine if that was the case).

Comment: @Lance: if you happen upon a rare question that shouldn't be re-opened and isn't a duplicate, then feel free to flag a moderator down and ask them to lock it. Make a good case for the value of that specific Q&A though... If it's been closed for a while, a safe assumption might well be that no one really cares to see it live.

Comment: @Shog9, I've flagged two for `Protect` status today that were linked from the Newsletter (though they'd be better going to what envisioned Programmers to become).  I'm sure the views count is one of the metrics for how `useful` a question might be.

Comment: @Lance: please be aware that "Protected" questions are those where *low-rep users* are prevented from answering. They can still be closed, deleted, re-opened, edited, etc. Additionally, "protecting" a closed question is pointless (since no one can answer a closed question).

Comment: @shog9, Yes, I understand that we don't need both `Protect` and `Closed`, neither of the questions I flagged were closed.  [One of the questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122784/hidden-net-base-class-library-classes) should probably be locked (has useful content, but no reason to see more being added), and [one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169713/whats-the-toughest-bug-you-ever-found-and-fixed) should just be migrated, but since Programmers changed its focus, there is no place to migrate it to, so it should probably be locked also....

Comment: The second one isn't useful, just entertaining, and would only be kept as a classic post, never to be repeated.

Comment: From the first 4 broad categories of appropriates per the FAQ: "software tools commonly used by programmers." I mean seriously, if comparing and contrasting tools and looking for advice on additional resources is so broad and subjective it needs to get shot down at every post, what is Stack Overflow other than a "do my homework for me" site? It just seems like I bump into more and more of this on the site as more people get the power to control content and I don't like it at all.

Comment: @Erik, yes, but questions that ask for lists don't fit well on this site, which is why they're disallowed.  I hope you understand all the comment discussion wasn't related to your two specific highlighted questions.

Answer (score 3):

[This is not terribly different from Shark vs. Gorilla](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).

At best, it's simply rephrasing to **"which animal is best?"*** and nothing good can come of that. Anything that does is 100% accidental.

(I sometimes see the argument made that you will occasionally get good answers to such questions,  which isn't *untrue* … but that's like assuming everyone who visits our site is a genius programmer with a penchant for writing. Yes, in *that* mythical land, any question, no matter how crazy, bad, or off-topic, will get a friggin' *amazing* answer. But back here in reality...)

<sub>* Humans, obviously.</sub>