# Please just close garbage questions, instead of moving them to Programmers SE

Tags: discussion, software-engineering-se, question-quality, migrated-questions

### https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72304/what-is-architectural-infracture

> Googling does not helped. I haved heared about it in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyNPeTn8fpo&feature=channel_page

I can't really see anything salvageable here.  It's hard not to take this as an insult to Programmers.

Am I on my own or should this question just have been closed as "Not a real question" while still on SO?  If it should have, how to we get the message out the Programmers doesn't want garbage, either?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/149432)

Comment: -1 for a duplicate question.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I would argue it's a slightly different question, but you are free to disagree.  What I was seeing here was questions that *should have been closed anyway, anywhere*, not just questions inappropriate for Programmers FAQ but "liked" (upvoted) by the community, which is what most of the links in the toilet bowl question are.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is a bummer, since the golden rule of migration is **don't migrate crap**.

> #### migrated to programmers.stackexchange.com by Cody Gray, Ladislav Mrnka, Aron Rotteveel, Joe, Graviton 40 mins ago

No diamond moderators were involved in this case though.

When this happens, simply flag for mod attention as "low quality migration" for now, and we'll delete it.

Note that there is some basic migration protection in place based on tags; a migrated question must have at least one tag in common on the target site before being migrated. We might institute more later...

Comment: It's somewhat unfair to call out these users, since one or two of them might have indeed voted to close as *"not a question"*.

Comment: This used to happen all the time on Super User; everything got dumped there. Not programming related? Super User, where else?

Comment: Yeah, for the record, I *did not* vote to migrate that. Some of the other users apparently disagreed.

Comment: @cody oh sure, "Cody Gray" .. did you even "post" that "comment"? :)

Comment: That's a clever rule.  I support more like that.

Comment: @Jeff: How does the "one tag in common" work for (say) questions tagged [tag:latex] on SO? There is no such tag on TeX.SE because it would be redundant...

Comment: @yoda that is an intrinsic tag, e.g. it is there for the purpose of migration matching but not visible on the site because EVERY question on wordpress would be tagged [wordpress], [apple] on apple, [android] on android, etc etc etc etc etc

Comment: @Jeff: Ah, invisible tags... got it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of the sites *want* garbage, it does seem odd that this made it to Programmers...

When the item was flagged as "Moderator Attention" so that a Moderator could move it (I'm presuming here that it was suggested by whomever flagged the item that it should go to Programmers), the Moderator should have made the decision that the question didn't meet either sites requirements and cleaned it up as per any other garbage.

Likely you'll need a Moderator to let you know why the decision was made to move it...

Comment: It was migrated by 3k users not moderators, which you won't now be able to see unless you are 10k [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818661/what-is-architectural-infracture?noredirect=1) since it was deleted (thankfully) on both.

Comment: @Renesis, thanks for the extra info...of the 5 3k+ users, presumably 1 of them should have realised it was rubbish

Comment: Although it seems from @Michael Petrotta that this may not even have been the desired outcome of each user...

Comment: yep, majority rules in votes to close.