# Is it safe to kill the [workplace] tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

After seeing a rather poor quality question on SO, I noticed that SO has a [workplace](/questions/tagged/workplace) tag with no wiki.  The only purpose of the tag is to help find some really bad quality questions about career advice and workplace advice - many of which are closed, some that still need to be closed, and most of which that need to be deleted.

Fortunately there are only 37 questions most of which are asking questions about the workplace and/or career advice, but there appears to be [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566380/chrome-snippets-vs-workplace) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187221/extending-filenet-p8-3-5-worplace-with-custom-gui-and-code) might be programming related (although the first is not a good on-topic question as it is just asking for a comparison).

Does the [workplace](/questions/tagged/workplace) tag have a legitimate purpose that I am not aware of - specifically related to a library or function that is being asked in the 1 programing question?  Or is it safe to remove it from all of the posts and let Trogdor do his thing?

Comment: Came here to ask the same thing, but didn't think it was worth it for <50 questions. The only question I saw that looked legitimate was this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187221/extending-filenet-p8-3-5-worplace-with-custom-gui-and-code, and the tag can probably still be removed in that case.  I've voted to close all others that were open, and will start deleting once 8 PM rolls around tonight, since they're *waaaaay* off topic

Comment: I'm working my way through them, closing the questions that need closed.  I haven't gotten to the one you found yet, but that does look legit.  I'll let the 10K'ers work their magic so I don't have to raise 30 flags for deletions.

Comment: @LBT I removed the tag from the one legit post, but I'll leave it on the off-topic posts for now so we can find them easier until everything that needs to be delete is deleted.

Comment: [status-completed]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: These questions have been burninated]

Answer (score 7):

On this note, please [don't just migrate questions to The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/how-can-we-get-se-to-stop-migrating-questions-which-clearly-need-work-here).

Some of the questions previously tagged looked, from title at least, like they could be suitable for migration. But a very good percentage too looked like they would need to be closed initially (which becomes a pain then, see my above post).

Comment: The large majority of these questions *can't* be migrated. They're just plain too old. I don't understand why people are even concerned with migration here.

Comment: @animuson - Because we get quite a few bad questions migrated to TWP with the only qualification being that they were kind of about working.

Comment: @animuson because the original answer suggested migrating them to programmers.  And you know how that idea is <sarcasm>*loved*</sarcasm> but that community

Comment: @animuson see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196485/193412) - simply because something relates to work does NOT make it a good question for The Workplace...

Comment: I'm aware of the other answer, and I downvoted it simply because they can't be migrated in the first place, hence the answer cannot be useful. No need to discuss migration when migration isn't even an option.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting Migrating all the questions though, bad questions should be shut down. If I had the ability, I'd only migrate what would be considered a very good question on the recipient site.

Answer (score -3):

I'd suggest it probably is safe.

I originally mentioned Programmers as a potential home for these questions, but I was wrong.
I'm a bad man.

Many workplace based questions related to the industries SO serves are better suited on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ where many of the users are in a better position to answer.

[workplace](/questions/tagged/workplace) isn't programming specific.
SO is for programming - relates to specific coding discussions.
Workplace is for Workplace based issues.

I think [workplace](/questions/tagged/workplace) items should be migrated to Workplace if they are able

Comment: You better not let [Yannis](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/25936/yannis-rizos) see this answer.  None of these questions are really appropriate for programmers.  Some might be ok for [Workplace.SE] with some work, but all are too old to migrate

Comment: I love how you linked him. I'm now scared of the wroth. I'm not a regular on Programmers, but I have seen many workplace based discussions there, hence my association - I'll edit to reflect this and avoid myself any more embarrassment :(

Comment: I'm not a regular either, but I'm active enough on MSO that I know the scope of [Programmers.SE] changed a number of years ago to be more focused on actual programming issues and not personal advice

Comment: [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Comment: [Workplace apparently doesn't want them either](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/how-can-we-get-se-to-stop-migrating-questions-which-clearly-need-work-here)

Comment: @Ampt yeah but that question was a bad one

Comment: @Ampt in general, Migration except to meta sites is almost completely broken because no one understands how to migrate.  Specifically questions should not be migrated unless they are 100% on-topic and a good quality question.  The rule is "Don't migrate crap".

Comment: [What's the golden rule of question migrations? Don't. Migrate. Crap.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/165773 "quote source")

Comment: All these downvotes :( I feel vulnerable.

Comment: @Ampt Agreed keep them away from us.